# Preguntas de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!"

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, preguntas, trabajo-escolar

Tengo la sensación que la mayoría de las preguntas en la etiqueta `C++`<sup>1</sup> consisten en el autor de la pregunta pidiendo que le hagan un ejercicio de programación.

En mi opinión, estas preguntas son en cierta manera dañinas por los siguientes motivos:

1. **Suelen ser de baja calidad**: Una combinación de preguntas repetidas, mal redactadas, mal expresadas o poco claras.
2. **Estos usuarios no enriquecen el sitio**: Suelen ser usuarios que publican unas pocas preguntas (habitualmente de baja calidad, ver nº1) y tras recibir (o no) la respuesta que buscan no vuelven a participar en el sitio (ya sea preguntando de nuevo o respondiendo preguntas ajenas).
3. **No aprenden**: Tal vez lo peor es que con la actitud de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio!" no están aprendiendo a programar y no pueden volverse un usuario útil en el futuro.
4. **A veces tienen limitaciones inapropiadas**: En ocasiones las mejores soluciones a un problema pasan por utilizar librerías o constructos del lenguaje que están explícitamente *prohibidos* por la naturaleza del ejercicio (no por limitaciones del IDE o el compilador), esto puede obligar a responder con la solución menos adecuada al problema tratado con lo que puede afectar negativamente a aquellos que usen esa respuesta como referencia.

Creo recordar que SO en inglés tuvo durante un tiempo la etiqueta`homework`para marcar estas preguntas y por lo que he podido ver a día de hoy no existe (o jamás existió, no estoy seguro) pero suele ser un tema controvertido como puede verse en el [Meta de SO-en](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework).

No se me ocurre ninguna solución para aumentar la calidad de las preguntas`homework`y contribuir a que los usuarios que realizan ese tipo de preguntas se vuelvan unos colaboradores de calidad para el sitio SO-es.

¿Qué opinión tenéis al respecto?

---

<sup>1</sup>No puedo opinar sobre otras etiquetas, pues solo soy capaz de aportar conocimiento de calidad en dicha etiqueta.

Comment: Esta discusión se puede extrapolar a prácticamente la mayoría de las preguntas con lenguajes de programación que se han cerrado últimamente.

Comment: La etiqueta `[homework]` existió, pero no debería existir. Es demasiado genérica y no aporta ninguna información útil sobre la pregunta.

Comment: La etiqueta [homework] si aporta información útil sobre la pregunta y sobre el tipo de respuesta. Por ejemplo hay que evitar el uso de librerías de terceros ya que al ser [homeworks] se espera que se haga a mano.
Personalmente crearía la etiqueta y obligaría a usarla, para que la gente,  que no le gusta hacer los deberes de los demás, puedan filtrarlas.

Comment: Que tema tan complicado, muchas respuestas y solo 1 tiene varios votos a favor

Comment: La etiqueta [homework] no aporta nada útil porque no es nada especial y es increíblemente genérica: puede utilizarse con ejercicios de Java, SQL, HTML, C, PHP, Caligrafía, Matemáticas, Origami... y sería correcta en todas ellas, lo que hace que pierda completamente su valor para identificar y categorizar preguntas (que es el objetivo de una etiqueta). Por eso se dejó de usar en el sitio en inglés, y por eso no debería crearse/usarse en este sitio.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Las etiquetas son combinables, así pues una `homework` con [tag:c++] es evidente que trata de tareas de `C++`; sin embargo si que es cierto que aparentemente fue eliminada de SO-en y el criterio seguido en ese sitio hermano podría ser válido en este.

Comment: No sólo se eliminó en SO-en ([y en Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/blacklist-homework)) sino que además se incluyó en una lista negra para que no se pudiera usar nunca más. Totalmente de acuerdo en que ese criterio podría (y debería) ser válido aquí también, somos una comunidad nueva y hacemos las cosas a nuestra manera, pero no aprender de los errores cometidos en otros sitios de SE sería un gran fallo que puede costar mucho (en SO-en tuvieron que revisar/editar más de 20.000 preguntas con la etiqueta [homework])

Comment: La ingenuidad es algo maravilloso. Te puedes pasar años programando en un lenguaje, te llega un novato con una pregunta tonta y luego resulta que no era tan tonta. Que estabas equivocado respecto a una cuestión básica pese a ser un experto. No pongamos trabas innecesarias a los nuevos. Si una pregunta de ejercicio "demuestra trabajo de investigación, es útil y clara" votemos positivo. Si "Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación, es confusa o poco útil" votemos negativo sea o no de ejercicio.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos si te fijas doy varios motivos por los que lo comentas, no se da en este tipo de preguntas: Baja calidad, No aportan, No participan, No aprenden, Limitaciones absurdas. La mayoría de preguntas de "Hacedme el ejercicio" ni siquiera muestran un intento de resolución por parte del usuario, así que lo de "*llega un novato con una pregunta tonta que resulta que no era tan tonta*" no es aplicable en este contexto :)

Comment: Esos "motivos" son muy opinables, PaperBirdMaster. Para para ti [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22410/como-imprimir-elementos-repetidos-de-una-stdlist-en-c-sin-usar-bucles/50350#50350) tiene limitaciones absurdas, para mi tiene limitaciones interesantes. Además me parece de calidad y enriquecedora. Y despues de hacer esa pregunta también hizo dos respuestas que fueron bien recibidas. No es un usuario vampiro. Luego ya no ha tenido actividad, pero quizás el problema no es el usuario sino la pésima acogida que el sitio le ha dado.

Comment: Esos motivos a mi me parecen objetivos. Podemos discutirlos en el chat si  quieres @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos en cuanto a la pregunta que me has enlazado ¿cuándo he dicho yo que me parezca tener limitaciones absurdas?, por favor no asumas cuál va a ser mi juicio. Por limitaciones absurdas me refiero a [cosas como esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50513/mi-archivo-no-guarda-un-valor-entero-en-c?noredirect=1#comment89096_50513) en que un profesor pide al alumnado usar una librería determinada en lugar de dejar que el alumnado busque una solución por si mismo.

Answer (score 9):

El problema de las preguntas tipo `homework` es que nos seguirá por mucho tiempo porque esperamos crecer como comunidad regularmente. Esto requiere nuevos usuarios que nunca han usado la plataforma y que desconocen las reglas.

Necesitamos ayudar a los nuevos en las mejores prácticas y así asegurar la educación y el respeto de las reglas. No podremos evitar este problema pero sí podemos prevenir que un usuario se sienta mal y nunca regrese al sitio por cometer un error de novato. La manera en que nosotros como usuarios regulares respondamos a las actividades de los nuevos usuarios fomentará el clima que queremos sentir en esta comunidad.

Es responsabilidad nuestra el crear una atmósfera de aprendizaje junto con un ambiente caluroso y amigable.  A nadie nos gusta recibir critica sin ayuda para mejorar el error. Habrá usuarios cuya meta es el beneficio personal sin respeto a las reglas pero esto no nos debe influenciar o causar una generalización de cada usuario nuevo. No todos son egoístas.

Mi sugerencia es simplemente el educar a los que hagan este tipo de pregunta por medio de los comentarios a que mejoren sus preguntas antes de recibir las respuestas que buscan.

Answer (score 7):

También soy de la opinión que este tipo de preguntas, bien hechas, podrían enriquecernos a todos. A menudo damos por sabidos ciertos patrones a la hora de diseñar un programa que a un novato le cuesta de entender.

Lo difícil es lograr que el usuario explique algo que todavía no conoce bién. Muchas veces he pensado en poner en la respuesta lo que he interpretado que se está preguntando. Pero son muchas más las veces que me he preguntado si la respuesta que le puedo dar le va a servir de algo si no tiene aún un nivel adecuado para entenderlo.

En mi experiencia, muy pocas veces el usuario añade más información sobre su problema, tal vez algún comentario sobre si es lo que busca. Claramente refleja la *"inmediatez"* con la que esperaba la respuesta, sin importar nada lo que pueda aportar su pregunta al resto de la comunidad.

Lamentablemente, mi criterio es ignorar (cerrar) aquellas preguntas tipo `homework` en las que no vea un mínimo trabajo hecho por el usuario. Como mucho añadir un comentario con un enlace a un tutorial o a la documentación de la librería que tiene que mirarse.

Answer (score 4):

Si se fijan, existe un alto indice de preguntas que se reponden y que tienen incluso varios puntos de *up*, pero los usuarios no las aceptan formalmente con el botón aceptar. Fíjense, muy pocas preguntas se marcan como aceptadas. Y creo que se debe a este tipo de personajes, que preguntan, obtienen su respuesta y luego se van de la comunidad. En lo personal intento aportar, dejando links en los comentarios a estos usuarios, sobre como preguntar correctamente, pero no se si muchos se darán el trabajo de leerlos.

En mi opinión, no creo que sean un gran aporte.

Answer (score 3):

Para mi el problema es que se responden, les dan upvotes a las respuestas y luego las ponen en espera, ya cuando han saciado al usuario, en vez de ponerlas en espera desde el principio y desalentar a estos usuarios a hacer estas preguntas que no aportan nada o mucho.

Por ejemplo estas preguntas [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11069/migrar-android-a-phonegap) y [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10943/alguien-sabe-pasar-matrices-como-par%C3%A1metro-de-una-clase-o-funci%C3%B3n-a-otra?) de pobre calidad, que parecen tarea de investigación.

Comment: No había visto esas preguntas. Y sin embargo tampoco veo que sean genéricas. Son precisas y muy comunes en los que empiezan. Otra cosa que sea la facilidad de preguntar sin buscar antes (en eso les doy la razón). Pero si queremos que se aprenda, ayudar a principiantes y menos principiantes (todos podemos aprender más y mejor), estas son preguntas aceptables en mi opinión.

Answer (score 3):

Ante todo educación, porque como ya alguno ha comentado, no queremos que los principiantes salgan corriendo de aquí. Amablemente tenemos que indicarles la forma más apropiada de abordar las preguntas y sobretodo que estén centradas en algo concreto.
Yo como principiante en este foro y también como programador a veces me asaltan dudas difíciles de plantear así que creo que hay que armarse de paciencia y no dejar de insistir a los nuevos que revisen sus preguntas para que cumplan un mínimo de calidad.

Answer (score 3):

Debemos atraer a los nuevos usuarios (y conservar a los usuarios existentes) con contenido de calidad. Las preguntas en comento, en su mayoría, poco aportan a la calidad de los contenidos.

Además, en otro orden de ideas, en mi opinión, estamos obligados a cumplir y hacer cumplir con las normas de calidad de la comunidad; cualquier otra acción (enseñar, educar, acompañar o tutelar a los nuevos usuarios) es una decisión personal.

Por lo tanto, yo también propongo que se utilice la etiqueta `[homework]` para que aquellos que no estén interesados puedan filtrarla y quienes tengan los recursos y el interés, igualmente, las identifiquen más fácilmente.

Answer (score 3):

Es difícil encontrar una solución a este tema. Yo creo que el problema no son en sí las preguntas tipo *homework* si no los usuarios que carecen de respeto; se puede ser nuevo en una comunidad, en un lenguaje de programación, en internet incluso, pero hay ciertas cosas que transcienden todo esto ya que entran en la categoría del sentido común, el respeto a los demás, la convivencia.

Estoy de acuerdo en que hay que intentar educar, explicar con paciencia a los nuevos ciertas reglas sobre cómo hacer las preguntas o el funcionamiento de la comunidad pero hay ciertos usuarios a los cuales todo eso se la "refanfinfla" ya que vienen a preguntar algo que necesitan con urgencia, que probablemente han posteado en 30 lugares distintos y a la mitad de esos sitios nunca volverán porque ya tienen la respuesta o porque ni saben dónde preguntaron, no dan *feedback* y nadie sabe si las soluciones les sirvieron o no han vuelto porque les atropelló un autobús al cruzar la calle.

La gente que contesta está usando parte de su tiempo para ayudar y merecen el respeto del que pregunta, intentando dar la información más clara posible, preguntando cosas concretas y demostrando que has trabajado por tu cuenta y buscado sobre problemas parecidos antes de plantear tus dudas. Esto no tiene nada que ver con la experiencia o el conocimiento, si no como ya he dicho con el respeto y la convivencia en comunidad, en internet y en la vida.

Sobre si tiene que haber o no una etiqueta `[homework]` no creo que ayude en nada con este tipo de gente que describo ya que probablemente ni la usen, quizá en otros casos sirva para filtrar o ayude a entender limitaciones que tenga el problema planteado al tratarse de ejercicios.

**P.D.:** Una opción para no contestar de mala manera es dedicar tanto tiempo a la respuesta como el dedicado a la pregunta:
- ¿Sabéis cómo hacer una calculadora en JavaScript?
- Sí.

Comment: He tenido la tentación de responder como siguieres en tu PD varias veces; no lo he hecho porque no quiero perder reputación ;P

Comment: Lo pones en un comentario y ya. No, solo era una broma, en realidad yo lo que hago en cabrearme cuando veo preguntas así, luego recapacito y paso a otra cosa, no merece la pena gastar tiempo en eso.

Answer (score 2):

Para mí, en general (o por lo menos en los threads que suelo participar) veo mucho contenido de este tipo. En realidad abundan las preguntas tipo ejercicios o incluso, preguntas de muy baja calidad, por el contenido investigativo.

Atribuyo lo último a lo siguiente:

Vivimos en un tiempo en el que los jóvenes lo buscan todo en internet (tooodo) y rápidamente se ha esparcido esa cultura de `pregúntale a san Google`, entonces esto provoca que alimentes de conocimiento a un hambriento que se niega a cocinarse un plato, por muy sencillo que sea.

Entonces, habrán quienes realmente tienen una carencia en sus preguntas porque realmente no tienen la experiencia (están empezando a desarrollar), pero esto no es excusa porque ese individuo puede realizar un esfuerzo en tratar de solventar su problema por sus medios (aunque sean limitados), cursos `dummies` los hay por montones para iniciar e irse empapando en el asunto y si se ve que aún con esto no es suficiente, entonces se opta por publicar una pregunta sostenida sobre un intento digno pero sin resultado, de conseguir una solución.

Servirá de mucho pues; pienso, mantener limpio el sitio de preguntas duplicadas, no sé hasta que punto mantener preguntas con un perfil que no sea tan principiante, pero se debe buscar la manera de que el sitio sea un sitio de referencia seria y resultado de investigación y esfuerzo por parte de todos; tanto por los que pregunta como por los que responden.

Otro punto, quizá un poco fuera de este contexto; pero si llevando el hilo del ambiente caluroso y amable que propone alguien por allí. En este sitio hay personas que se dedican a indisponer las respuestas de usuarios con menos 'reputación' y lo peor es que lo hacen en los comentarios de la propia pregunta o respuesta, dando así, una mala imagen y un mal ambiente entre 'expertos' que es percibido por el usuario nuevo. Me ha tocado ser algo brusco con este tipo de personas porque en lo personal, no lo hago con nadie. Pero eso es grano de otro costal.

Lo importante es tratar de que el sitio esté a la altura y siendo honestos hay mucho por hacer.

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que siempre puedes aprender de todo, hay usuarios menos experimentados que otros y para ello es este espacio, ahora si algún colega solicita; "Como hace mi sistema..." con el mínimo esfuerzo de Copiar y Pegar el código que solicitó, entonces no solo se deberá tomar juicio de quien solicita, también de quien aporta.

Cada programador que solicita ayuda deberá entender que para lograr un mejor nivel en su carrera laboral no solo deberá copiar y pegar...

Answer (score 2):

Desde que iniciaron las clases en algunos países en Latinoamérica (Marzo-Abril), percibo un aumento en las preguntas del tipo: "ayuda con mi tarea". Sería mucho pedir **poner un Banner enorme (de preferencia con lucecitas de neón) para que todos los usuarios lean cómo hay que formular preguntas** y siendo un poco más estrictos los nuevos usuarios: *una vez que hayan leído las reglas tengan la chance de preguntar, así bien informados se mejorará la calidad de las preguntas.*

Este sitio se mantiene con la buena voluntad de todos los que paseamos por aquí, a modo de sugerencia recuerden ese Banner para leer las reglas de formulación de preguntas, y el diseño del Banner de preferencia con lucecitas de neón para darle ese toque futurista.

Answer (score 2):

Soy bastante nuevo en este sitio, no así en otros foros; vine porque en SOen apareció una invitación. Tienen razón en lo que a no hacer los deberes de otros se refiere, incluso, si se trata de desarrolladores con alto nivel, que también suelen buscar la manera de ahorrarse pensar problemas complejos.

Pero, en lo que al buen trato y el respeto se refiere, deben mantenerse, no importa cual sea la calidad o pertinencia de la pregunta. Pongo un ejemplo: abandoné para siempre el foro linux ubuntu, porque mi respuesta de ayuda a alguien que la necesitaba para salvar su info usando una versión (14.04) que ya no contaba con soporte, fue baneada porque 14.04 era obsoleto y no estaba soportado: o sea que los del 3er mundo que no tienen recursos para actualizarse permanentemente deben jo....se. Aquí, espero, no debe prosperar una censura similar.

Creo, que las preguntas se formulan motivadas por necesidades. Y, si uno, libremente, tomo la decisión de ayudar, debe hacerlo de la mejor manera. Si alguien pregunta ¿cómo hago mi tarea? quizás movido porque su maestro formuló la pregunta tan genéricamente que no puede enfocarla, así se trate del manido factorial: se le puede ofrecer un par de sugerencias y un enlace correcto para que pueda documentarse y abordarla.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que debamos prohibir preguntas de tipo homework mientras sean buenas preguntas. El problema es que muy a menudo no son buenas preguntas.

Creo que uno de los principales problemas es que nos faltan motivos de cierre. En "debería ser cerrada..." -> no "relacionado porque..." nos faltan las opciones que tiene stackoverflow original. Con estas podríamos cerrar de forma adecuada muchas de estas preguntas y al que preguntó le saldría un mensaje apropiado del motivo de cierre.

Creo que de los motivos de cierre que hay en stackoverflow original en "no relacionado porque..." deberíamos pasar aquí al menos "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software...", "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must..." y "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or...".

Answer (score -3):

La publicación es vieja pero creo que sigue siendo un tema actual.

Según lo que he leído aquí en META y las conversaciones que he sostenido con muchos usuarios me ha hecho pensar que hay muchos que no entienden cómo funciona el sitio (*o seré yo el que no entiende?*)

El sitio pretende crear una base de conocimientos con un formato de preguntas y respuestas, una FAQ con esteroides. OK

Pero si esto fuera todo, solo se deberían aceptar preguntas:

- Bien formadas, tanto en forma y fondo.
- Gramática y ortografía aceptables
- Acotadas
- Con ejemplo mínimo
- Y principalmente, que sirvan a muchos usuarios y no solo al que pregunta.

Yo creo que no hay 10 preguntas a la semana de este tipo (y soy generoso)

La verdad es que el sitio se sostiene gracias a usuarios que vienen a preguntar por la solución de **SU** problema, sin interés alguno en generar esta base de conocimientos

Entonces "Hacedme el ejercicio" (en el sentido amplio) es la esencia de que va todo esto. Alguien tiene un problema y otro se lo resuelve.

¿Alguien se ha preguntado, porque en vez de cerrar preguntas, no se hace el proceso inverso. Que las preguntas ingresen a una cola y se aprueben para ser publicadas y respondidas?

Es porque no habrían ni 10 preguntas a la semana, y con 10 preguntas nadie participaría activamente en el sitio, por lo que rápidamente se transformarían en cero.

Ahora sobre las tareas del tipo académicas, existen preguntas y preguntas, esta [publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4125/301324) resume 100% lo que pienso.

Hace unos meses respondí una pregunta del tipo "necesito una función que haga X", algo puntual, "respondible" y además que puede ser de interés a muchos más usuarios.

Un usuario me comentó: **"No estamos aquí para resolver problemas ajenos"**. Y yo me preguntó, habré estado respondiendo mis propias preguntas todo este tiempo??

Otro me escribió: **"No es la idea de dar una solución gratis, debes esperar a que el OP demuestre esfuerzo"** Es decir el OP me paga con su esfuerzo??? Mira que no me ha llegado el depósito.

Y de estos comentarios tengo muchos más, que van en esta misma línea y me animaron a publicar esto y a sostener que hay usuarios que no entienden de que va el sitio, o a lo menos tienen una visión utópica de él

Ahora bien, las preguntas que vomitan un enunciado de 20 puntos, son cerradas al instante.  Y bien cerradas, porque son demasiado amplias. Entonces, debo suponer que el problema pasa por el otro tipo de preguntas, la del tipo acotado y perfectamente respondibles, pero que el usuario no ha demostrado ese tan codiciado esfuerzo.

A mi parecer, lo que molesta es la desfachatez en la forma de la pregunta, que se resumen en el título de esta publicación "¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!". Entonces asumimos que es un vago, y me recuerda a mi compañero de trabajo que también es un vago, y por eso ni yo ni nadie debería ayudarlo y el que lo haga se ganará mi negativo. Y bueno, el asunto no iba de preguntas y respuestas?

Sobre los puntos señalados por el autor:

1. **Suelen ser de baja calidad**:  Al igual que el 99% del resto de las preguntas
2. **Estos usuarios no enriquecen el sitio:** TODAS las preguntas enriquecen al sitio, porque le da movimiento. Las malas preguntas se cierran, pero no dejan de haber aportado su granito de arena.
3. **No aprenden**: Si se aprende mirando código y más cuando lo explican
4. **A veces tienen limitaciones inapropiada**s: En qué quedamos, importa o no  qué aprendan?. Porque este tipo de ejercicios es la base del aprendizaje. Además, si no fuera por este tipo de condiciones la cantidad de preguntas estaría limitado a la cantidad de funciones que tiene un lenguaje.

Y sobre la pregunta que se deja planteada:

**¿Como aumentar la calidad de las preguntas?**

Vuelvo a insistir en el punto de que muchos usuarios no entienden el sitio. SO tiene un modelo iterativo (como las wiki). No hay problema en una pregunta o respuesta mal formada e imperfecta, esto lo podemos corregir editando la publicación. Lo importante es que exista la publicación

Hay casos insalvables, esas se cierra. Y las que están en un área gris se pide al autor que coloqué los antecedentes que falten.

Pero no esperemos que las preguntas salgan del horno perfectas, eso no va a pasar. Es totalmente impráctico poner la carga en usuarios que no les interesa el sitio.

Comment: El 99% de las preguntas del sitio **no son de baja calidad**, ya que se modera el sitio. **No todas las preguntas enriquecen el sitio**, las preguntas de baja calidad o aquellas no relacionadas con el sitio lo empobrecen. Ese tipo de usuarios no suelen aprender, [ya expliqué por qué](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/588/2742). Respecto a las limitaciones inapropiadas, también [lo expliqué](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/588/2742) en mi publicación.

Comment: Las preguntas que van quedando pueden ser que sean de calidad. Pero el grueso de preguntas que ingresan al sistema día a día no lo son. Algunas se mejoran, otras se toleran y otras se cierran.  Lo que entendí de tu publicación es tu apuntas a las preguntas recién creadas (antes que se moderen), y bueno la solución pasa por moderarlas, pero hay que asumir que el trabajo se lo llevarán los usuario comprometidos. Y pese a todo, yo soy de la idea, que incluso las malas preguntas (las horribles!) ayudan a generar movimiento en el sitio en el día a día, y que a la larga se borran así que no hay daño

Comment: No, lo que digo en mi publicación apunta concreta y exclusivamente a las preguntas de tipo "*¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!*" no a las preguntas recién creadas en general.

Comment: Piensa el lado contrario. Un vago viene, copia el enunciado, lo pega y recibe una respuesta. Luego copia el código y se va. Hizo una pregunta muy especifica que no aporta a nadie mas que a el, y quedó sin aprender nada. Esta gente ni siquiera da atención a los comentarios. Muchos de ellos, solo quieren copiarse.Tenemos que tener seguridad. Aunque, te doy la razón con que algunas preguntas y respuestas solo ayudan al que preguntó y los que responden (respondiendo también se aprende). Yo creo que en realidad, el objetivo del sitio es ayudar y aprender entre todos (ambas cosas).

Answer (score -4):

Iba a añadir un comentario a la respuesta de @JuanManuelDoren criticando su postura, pero tanto la pregunta como las respuestas ya tienen varios años.
Recientemente he estado leyendo preguntas y comentarios sobre los ChatGPT.
Mis propias conclusiones me llevan a realizar esta respuesta.

1. ¡Bienvenido al mundo ChatGPT!
2. ¡Ha nacido un nuevo paradigma! Sí, **un nuevo paradigma** tal y como suena.

   - Ha llegado la hora de que este sitio y otros similares, se conviertan en lo que deben ser, un sitio para resolver dudas, que no se proporcionan en las documentaciones.
   - Un sitio en el que cuando un usuario tenga un problema de lógica pueda encontrar a alguien que lo oriente para encontrar la solución.
   - Un sitio en el que se puedan obtener respuestas a preguntas académicas, que se enfocan a pedir una mejor explicación sobre un tema concreto, que no ha logrado entender de sus profesores. En algunos cursos los profesores se cierran en banda, esto se hace así porque lo digo yo o lo dijo el Gurú de turno, y las explicaciones son muy pobres (quizás, él no sepa la respuesta o tampoco la entienda. Que de haberlos, hailos.)
   - Un sitio en el que los que buscan respuestas fáciles de solo copiar y pegar *Copy-Paste* desaparezcan, ya que el ChatGPT se lo hace. *"siempre que sepa preguntar"*
   - Un sitio en el que se pueda preguntar sobre como salir de un punto en el que te encuentras estancado o que obtienes un error y no logras descubrir la causa (puede ser simplemente un *esp_acio*. que se te coló en el sitio menos conveniente, o la falta o exceso de una llave de cierre/apertura).

---

## ¿debemos responder...?

---

Como se menciona en varias respuestas, ***depende*** de si puedes aportar algo claro y conciso a la comunidad, con explicaciones documentadas *(usando comentarios en el código)* o con referencias *(Link's)* y no solo con **CÓDIGO** que a pesar de ¡resolver! el problema no aportan conocimiento.
Pero si puedes aportar conocimiento relativo a la pregunta **¡ADELANTE RESPONDE!**

---

*Alguien abrió ya, **la caja de Pandora**, tan solo deseo que haya quedado en el fondo, **la Esperanza** *

---

Comment: No entiendo el punto de tu respuesta. "Ha llegado la hora de que este sitio y otros similares, se conviertan en lo que deben ser, un sitio para resolver dudas, que no se proporcionan en las documentaciones": este sitio _ya lo es_, con una gran diferencia: [es.so] es un sitio de _preguntas y respuestas_ **específicas**, no un sitio en el que se explique lo que quiso dar a entender el profesor (porque solo el profesor lo sabrá) ya que eso hace que la pregunta sea basada en opiniones, por dar un ejemplo de lo que citaste. De todos modos, concuerdo con la última sección ("¿debemos responder?").

Comment: Me refiero a que este y otro sitios similares, no deberían ser un repositorio de códigos, debe ser un lugar de consultas, ChatGPT va a permitir lograrlo, ya que la increíble cantidad de preguntas que solo quieren obtener que les hagan el trabajo, tenderán a desaparecer. Si tengo un problema de conceptos o de lógica, me gustaría encontrar a un experto que me oriente y me explique **el porqué**, y no que me lo dé ya hecho. Quiero aprender, y no solo resolver el problema. Si alguien ya se encontró con ese problema y logro resolverlo, me gustaría saber como.

Comment: El sitio esta lleno de preguntas sin respuesta o con respuestas como las del compañero que menciono en mi respuesta, que pretenden confundir al *avispado* o con respuestas tan complejas que pocos comprenden y poco ayudan a quien se enfrente a problemas similares.

Comment: Esto es mas que un reposotorio de código. Es un lugar de consultas (no de guias, de consultas, quizá eso te hace pensar que es un repositorio). El problema con las respuestas demasiado simples, es que requerirían saber los niveles de conocimiento del otro (ni una ia podría). Por ejemplo, para entender un bucle for, debes entender el funcionamiento basico de una variable. El concepto de "complejo" es relativo a los conocimientos.

Answer (score -5):

no respoder y votar negativo es lo que se puede hacer 
(o responder mal para que saque mala nota ;-) )

Comment: jajajaja  _o responder mal para que saque mala nota ;-_ igual le podriamos decir que borre `C:\Windows` porque colisiona con su compilador/interprete