# ¿Qué hacer con las respuestas a los problemas tipo ejercicios?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, trabajo-escolar

Hoy revisando preguntas me encontré con esta: [Ejercicio de Programación en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/30732), la cual tiene solo este contenido:

> Tengo este ejercicio y quisiera saber cómo empiezo a resolverlo.
>
> Construye un programa en *C* que, al recibir como datos el costo de un artículo vendido y la cantidad de dinero entregada por el cliente, calcule e imprima el cambio que se debe entregar al cliente.

Obviamente, encontré la pregunta cerrada como demasiado amplia porque el autor no indica qué ha intentado para que nosotros podamos ayudarle. Sin embargo, veo que ha recibido una respuesta que al parecer atiende el problema. La pueden ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30734):

> Probá esto:
>
> ```c
> #include<stdio.h>
>
> int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
>   float costo, dineroEntregado;
>   printf("Ingrese el costo y lo que pagaron separado por un espacio, ambos en 0 para terminar\n");
>   while(scanf("%f %f", &costo, &dineroEntregado) == 2 && (costo != 0 || dineroEntregado != 0)){
>       printf("El vuelto es: %.2f\n", dineroEntregado - costo);
>       printf("Ingrese el costo y lo que pagaron separado por un espacio, ambos en 0 para terminar\n");
>   }
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Es un caso muy simple pero, en mi opinión, brindar una respuesta a este tipo de preguntas alienta a que los usuarios las sigan publicando. **¿Qué deberíamos hacer en estos casos hacia las respuestas? ¿Votarlas en negativo, ver si las eliminamos, dejarlas tal cual a 0 votos?**

Comment: 1. Considero que no estamos para hacerle los trabajos completos a NADIE. 2. Considero que al hacerle el trabajo completo no lo estamos ayudando sino mostrándole el camino fácil "Siempre puede haber alguien que lo haga por ti". 3. Es posible que la persona le pase la voz a sus amigos: "En SO te resuelven el problema, copia la tarea ahí". Resumen de mi opinión: **Eliminarlas**.

Comment: @Shaz convendría que lo pongas como respuesta mas no como comentario.

Comment: No estamos para hacerle el trabajo a nadie. Pero, ¿sí que estamos para impedir que otros le hagan el trabajo a alguien? Demasiadas ganas de controlar a los demás....

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos si te gusta trabajar gratis, genial. Pero esa no es la motivación del sitio. Para eso existen páginas como toptal donde puedes contratar alguien que resuelva todos tus problemas técnicos en base a tus requerimientos funcionales, tareas, o lo que fuese y les pagas.

Comment: No es la motivación, correcto. Y tampoco es la desmotivación. Que alguien le haga o le deje de hacer el trabajo a alguien es irrelevante a este sitio. Si la pregunta es útil y si la respuesta es útil para mucha gente y no solo para el autor original entonces es buena para este sitio.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos entiendo, pero ese no es el propósito de esta pregunta. Por favor deja de siempre estar buscando problemas o casos borde a las cosas. Entiendo que quieres colaborar, pero a veces parece que más es lo que buscas solo tener la razón en lo que dices y, aunque lo fuese, la manera en que lo haces es agobiante. Puedes seguir comentando lo que quieras aquí, pero yo lo dejo como caso cerrado.

Comment: El propósito de esta pregunta es saber qué hacer con las respuestas a preguntas de ejercicios. Decir que "el que alguien le haga o no a alguien el trabajo" no es un factor a la hora de decidir qué hacer con esas respuestas sí es relevante a esta pregunta. No soy el único que así piensa, también Shaz piensa que es relevante, aunque él en sentido contrario al mío. Resumen de mi opinión: Mantenerlas y mejorarlas.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos lo que digas campeón, lo que digas...

Answer (score 11):

Cuando me encuentro este tipo de preguntas, haciendo referencia a preguntas que piden un programa, las clasifico en dos tipos:

**Sin código, pero con análisis del problema.**

Hay algunas preguntas de este tipo que no tienen nada de código pero plantean bien lo que quieren, como lo quieren y el resultado esperado. Hay algunas veces que incluso dividen el problema en partes para que se entienda mejor.

A este tipo de preguntas les suelo dar una oportunidad, no voto negativo ni voto para cerrar este tipo de preguntas. Simplemente les dejo un comentario con recomendaciones sobre como pueden empezar o lo que deben usar. Todos hemos sido nuevos y sabemos lo difícil que es empezar y, la verdad, hacer un buen análisis antes de programar lo considero también como una parte de la programación, ya que es muy importante para saber lo que tienes que hacer después.

Si posteriormente veo en los comentarios que muestra interés por aprender y que no es simplemente "por favor hazme el ejercicio que yo no sé", le intento echar un cable dejando algo de código.

Lamentablemente, dentro de las preguntas que se podrían clasificar como "hazme el ejercicio" este es el tipo menos predominante.

**Sin código, exigiendo que le hagas los deberes.**

Este es el tipo que predomina de los dos por excelencia. El "HELP ME PLX!!", el "Hazme los deberes que hoy estoy vago y no me molesto ni en buscar en internet".

Este tipo de preguntas si que me molesta y les voto negativo y voto para cerrar la pregunta. Es el caso de la pregunta que has puesto en la descripción de tu pregunta. Simplemente proporciona el enunciado del ejercicio como si de una academia se tratara. Sin análisis, sin nada. Incluso muchas veces sin interés, ya que ni te agradecen que tu te hayas esforzado en prestarles atención.

Por eso, y porque no se molestan ni en hacer un análisis de lo que necesitan, cómo podrían plantear el ejercicio (aunque sea de palabra) ni del resultado esperado, creo que tampoco se merecen obtener una respuesta que les haga el trabajo y por eso siempre voto para cerrarlas.

**En cuanto a las respuestas, ¿qué hacemos?**

También dependería del tipo de pregunta:

- En el caso primero, la vería justificada, ya que incluso yo soy de los que contestan si finalmente veo que el OP muestra interés por lo que hace y ha hecho un buen análisis de la pregunta. De hecho, muchas veces valoro como positivo a gente que responde en este tipo de preguntas. Yo no les pondría ninguna "sanción".
- En el segundo caso es algo más complicado. ¿De verdad alguien que no se ha molestado en desarrollar su pregunta se merece que le hagan una respuesta con fundamento? La verdad, y creo que no soy el único en pensarlo, NO. Si no te esfuerzas, tampoco obtienes recompensa.

  Aún así, hay gente que contesta a este tipo de preguntas. ¿Qué hacemos con                            ellos? Por supuesto, si la respuesta está bien formulada y contesta a lo que el OP demanda en su pregunta, no podemos votarla como negativo ni eliminarla. Sería contraproductivo ya que las respuestas buenas, aún en preguntas malas, pueden servir a otros usuarios.

  Lo que yo hago es dejarles un comentario como que no deberían de responder a preguntas que no tienen ningún código ni análisis. Además, ya lo siento por los que contestan a este tipo de preguntas, no les doy ningún voto positivo. Es mi pequeña "sanción" como incentivo para que dejen de contestar a este tipo de preguntas. De esta manera, si ven que no reciben ningún punto en sus respuestas quiero pensar que dejarán de contestarlas (muchas veces ni el OP les vota, aún habiéndole resuelto el problema). Hay preguntas muy buenas en preguntas muy malas que no se merecen ese sitio.

  Por lo tanto, intentemos migrar a la gente buena a las preguntas con fundamento.

Comment: Esta respuesta caracteriza falsamente al autor de la pregunta. *exigiendo que le hagas los deberes*. No, en el texto que ha citado Mendoza no hay ninguna exigencia. Además esta respuesta cruzar una frontera peligrosa. *¿De verdad alguien que no se ha molestado en desarrollar su pregunta se merece que le hagan una respuesta con fundamento?* Aquí no evaluamos si las **personas** se merecen algo o no. Lo que evaluamos es si las **preguntas y respuestas** son útiles y claras. La pregunta que cita Mendoza es útil y clara. La respuesta que cita es útil, clara y muy mejorable.

Answer (score 1):

Yo al principio respondía las que miraba que podía ayudar, pero algunas son demasiado cantosas , yo por lo general, al principio solo ponía preguntas en caso de buscar y no encontrar.

Pero a la gente que redacta forma ejercicio y que los demás respondan, son gente que no aportan nada , no son preguntas *productivas* y ponen preguntas para que alguien les haga los deberes, hay que comentar sobre esto que es una práctica que no genera que seas un buen programador, en el día de mañana tendrás un título o algo así, pero no tendrás un conocimiento de saber enfrentarte tú ante un problema de programación y que en su defecto, los ejercicios tipo :

> Saca los numeros primos entre 1 y 30
>
> Conbierte los números binarios de esta array en decimales.

Son preguntas que te ayuan a tu cerebro a acostumbrarse a pensar y discurrir de una forma lógica. Para el día de mañana cuando te encuentres con un proyecto o un problema poder discurrirlo de una forma mejor y saber dividir esos problemas grandes en varios pequeños , en resumids cuentas usar el *ingenio*.

Confucio decía :

> Un problema grande se divide en problemas pequeños

Es una razón , porque tu con el tiempo usarás esos conocimientos de todos esos problemas pequeños , para solucionar problemas aún mas grandes , que será por lo que te pagarán, de otra forma como yo lo miro estarás formándote para tener un título y no la capacidad para demostrar que lo vale.

En resumen , que tampoco me quiero extender :

- Si la pregunta está redactada mas o menos en detalle , ha buscado
  información para solucionarlo y se mira interés y que no es usuario
  recien registrado, pues ayudo.
- En caso contrario, no ayudo sino oriento hacia la solución, ya que es
  mejor enseñar a pescar que dar pescado.

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de preguntas también me molestan mucho, hasta el punto que [hice un hilo en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado) al respecto, considero este tipo de preguntas **dañino** porque:

> 1. **Suelen ser de baja calidad**: Una combinación de preguntas repetidas, mal redactadas, mal expresadas o poco claras.
> 2. **Estos usuarios no enriquecen el sitio**: Suelen ser usuarios que publican unas pocas preguntas (habitualmente de baja calidad, ver nº1) y tras recibir (o no) la respuesta que buscan no vuelven a participar en el sitio (ya sea preguntando de nuevo o respondiendo preguntas ajenas).
> 3. **No aprenden**: Tal vez lo peor es que con la actitud de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio!" no están aprendiendo a programar y no pueden volverse un usuario útil en el futuro.
> 4. **A veces tienen limitaciones inapropiadas**: En ocasiones las mejores soluciones a un problema pasan por utilizar librerías o constructos del lenguaje que están explícitamente *prohibidos* por la naturaleza del ejercicio (no por limitaciones del IDE o el compilador), esto puede obligar a responder con la solución menos adecuada al problema tratado con lo que puede afectar negativamente a aquellos que usen esa respuesta como referencia.

#### ¿Qué hago?

Según el humor que tenga en el momento:

- Ignoro la pregunta.
- La comento.
- La respondo con un código ofuscado y de un nivel claramente superior al que un estudiante de programación debería tener.

Mi opción favorita es esa última porque ese código, aún ofuscado, puede ser una referencia útil a alguien al mismo tiempo que hace que la respuesta le sea inútil al *vago* que la pidió.

Pero esa última reflexión asume que el usuario copiará la respuesta tal cual y que el profesor que corrija el ejercicio será suficientemente avispado para ver que su alumno hace trampas... lo cuál (tal vez) es asumir mucho.

#### ¿Qué (creo que) debería hacer?

Opino que lo adecuado sería votar negativo e iniciar un proceso de votación de cierre. Teniendo en cuenta que tanto el voto negativo como el cierre son revertibles, se le da la oportunidad al usuario de corregir su pregunta y aprender algo en el proceso.

Pero eso vuelve a asumir que el usuario corregirá su actitud y aprenderá sobre la misma lo cuál (tal vez) es asumir mucho.

#### ¿Qué me gustaría hacer?

Me encantaría averiguar en qué centro estudia el *vago* y chivarme a su profesor.

Pero lo ideal sería que el sitio SOes y los centros que tienen la programación como asignatura pudiesen colaborar en harmonía.

Comment: Al igual que a @Error404, mi pregunta se centra en las respuestas, no en las preguntas. Creo haberlo puesto en el título, en la parte final y en las etiquetas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sinceramente, mi respuesta sin el contexto sobre las preguntas carecía de sentido. Y empecé por ahí y cuando acabé de hablar sobre las preguntas me olvidé del tema principal de la pregunta (a pesar de haberla leído varias veces). Igual es lo mismo que le ha pasado a @ PaperBirdMaster.

Comment: @Error404 el contexto ya está en el cuerpo de la pregunta, la verdad eso no me resulta provechoso porque **ya existe una forma de cómo tratar esas preguntas**. Por eso, mi preocupación se centra en **las respuestas**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Pero creo que era necesario hacer un incapié en que hay (lo que yo considero) dos tipos de preguntas en cuanto a pedir ejercicios y por lo tanto no todas se merecen la misma vara. O al menos no ví que fuera tan notable en tu pregunta y por eso quise recalcarlo. Por lo tanto, las respuestas en cada tipo se deberían de tratar de diferente manera (también desde mi punto de vista). De ahí que pusiera todo el contexto primero. Sin embargo, espero que al añadir el apartado de respuestas quedara clara mi postura.

Comment: @Error404 como te digo, eso ya está discutido [aquí](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/588/227) y [aquí](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/615/227) (por citar dos ejemplos). La finalidad de esta pregunta no es ahondar más en lo mismo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Perdón por hacer mención a las preguntas entonces. La verdad, pensé que sin el contexto anterior, no podía hacer mi respuesta. Que era un complemento obligatorio.