# Que hacer con los usuarios que contestan las preguntas tipo ejercicios

Tags: discusión, código-de-conducta, usuarios, trabajo-escolar

Iba a realizar una pregunta, de que hacer con los usuarios que publican las preguntas **tipo ejercicio** pero primero ya tienen una pregunta sobre esto ,entonces veo una pregunta que es como **"Necesito que hagan estos deberes"**, normal, le di mi voto negativo y apoye el comentario de otro usuario el cual le dice que no realice ese tipo de preguntas, pero al instante un usuario publico la respuesta.

Mi pregunta es que se pudiera hacer con este comportamiento, ya que el voto negativo se lo pueden poner al usuario que contestso la pregunta, pero igual ya le dio la respuesta al usuario flojo.

Esta es la pregunta a la que me refiero

[Secuencia no decreciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301167/secuencia-no-decreciente)

Comment: En el caso de esa pregunta, ni siquiera esta bien el algoritmo que le escribieron

Comment: Francisco en mi opinión no debes hacer nada con el usuario que responde(salvo un downvote si lo consideras necesario), nos deberiamos concentrar en la pregunta, es genial que des tu downvote por considerar que la pregunta es de mala calidad pero lo que sirve más es que votes para cerrar esa pregunta ya que es demasiado amplia y asi en un futuro poder eliminarla.

Comment: @eyllanesc entiendo

Comment: relacionado: 1) [¿Qué medidas serían eficaces para evitar hacerle los deberes a los vagos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1283/65), 2) [¿Qué hacer con las respuestas a los problemas tipo ejercicios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/976/65)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hace más de dos años sugerí algunas pautas en [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1305/65) a [¿Qué medidas serían eficaces para evitar hacerle los deberes a los vagos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1283/65). El resumen es

*Ponte en contacto con el autor de la respuesta ya sea por medio de un comentario, el chat o por medio de los datos de contacto que haya puesto en su perfil, mencionale el motivo y escucha.*

Punto y aparte de lo anterior, con la respuesta haz lo que harías normalmente con cualquier otra respuesta, vótala positivo, negativo o no votes con base en si responde la pregunta (cosa muy difícil de saber si la pregunta no es clara), su claridad, utilidad, etc.

Relacionado

- [¿Qué actitud es adecuada para estimular la buena calidad de preguntas y respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/201/65)
- [Veo muchas publicaciones malas y me enoja muchísimo. ¿Qué debo hacer al respecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/615/65)
- [¿Qué hacer con las respuestas a los problemas tipo ejercicios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/976/65)