# ¿Vamos a negar la posibilidad de preguntar al que no sabe nada?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

Esta pregunta es a raíz de otro ejemplo de maltrato a nuevos usuarios, en específico, el caso se refiere a una pregunta que ha quedado automáticamente borrada como resultado de un cierre incorrecto.

[Contar repeteciones de enteros C++, Array [cerrada]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43823/contar-repeteciones-de-enteros-c-array/43831)

> Buenas, el ejercicio dice lo siguiente
>
> "Diseñar un algoritmo que acepte de teclado un número natural n y
>   cuente el número de veces que se repite cada dígito dentro del mismo"
>
> Se que no he colgado mi código, pero es que no se por donde empezar,
>   es decir, si a cada elemento del array le meto mas de varios digitos
>   no se como realizar el recuento de cada dígito, mas bien el problema
>   lo tengo en separar el valor del array en digitos.

El motivo de cierre es

> cerrada como no está claro lo que se pregunta por J. Castro, ArtEze,
>   Mariano, Rene Limon, Jorgesys el 13 ene. a las 0:06

Lo cual es incorrecto. Está muy claro lo que pregunta. Ni siquiera hace falta saber de informática para entender qué significa contar el número de veces que se repite cada dígito en un número.

El usuario no ha puesto código porque ni siquiera sabe cómo empezar. ¿Vamos a negar la posibilidad de preguntar al que no sabe nada?

Imagino que el hecho de que sea un ejercicio académico y no cuente con nada de código se ve como un "give me the codez". Pero no es el caso. Este usuario sí hace preguntas con lo que ha intentado en temas que domina más y sí que responde a peticiones de mejorar la pregunta : [[1]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49014/al-eliminar-un-usuario-se-sobreescribe-con-el-siguiente)
No es un usuario de preguntar y abandonar. Es la clase de usuario que sin ser estelar (todavía) yo creo que acabará siendo un miembro valioso de la comunidad. **¿Le vamos a cortar las alas antes de que empiece a volar?**

Y luego está la cuestión de la respuesta. Como dice eferion

> Empezar a programar no es un camino de rosas... Si con estos problemas
>   de iniciación te damos una respuesta directa tu aprendizaje corre el
>   riesgo de estancarse. Yo te sugeriría resolver primero el ejercicio
>   con lápiz y papel y después llevar los pasos que has realizado a un
>   programa.

Totalmente de acuerdo con eferion. Pero también es posible dar una respuesta indirecta. Que es lo que hice yo. Alquien que quiera limitarse a copiar y pegar sin pensar no va a poder usar mi respuesta. Va a tener que leersela, entenderla y adaptar el código que he puesto para resolver su pregunta. Eso hizo el autor de la pregunta y con ello aprendió a pescar peces en vez de a que se los metan en la boca con una cuchara.

Comment: El cierre es correcto, en mi opinión, aunque tal vez no tanto el motivo. SEes **no es un sustituto de Google**. Como dice el [tour], las preguntas con demasiadas respuestas posibles o que requieran una respuesta muy extensa no funcionan muy bien en el formato tan cerrado de esta comunidad. Por otro lado, así funciona este sitio, los usuarios vamos a votar por cerrar como mejor nos parezca, aunque otras personas, como en este caso, no estén de acuerdo. Y el cierre no es incorrecto como dices, más bien **en tu opinión, es incorrecto**.

Comment: ¿Cómo puede ser un cierre correcto si el motivo no es correcto? Hagamos las cosas bien por favor.

Comment: El problema es que otros cinco o seis usuarios piensan diferente que tu. Así funciona el sitio. Imagina que pasaría si tuvieras que abrir una pregunta cada vez que un cierre te parece incorrecto. O imagina si eres tu quien debe decidir si una pregunta debe cerrarse o no. Estoy seguro que se comenten errores al cerrar preguntas (yo soy el primero en cometerlos), pero también estoy seguro que son la minoría y que debemos confiar en el criterio de los usuarios que se toman el tiempo de revisar las preguntas, de comentar y de votar. **Intento hacer las cosas bien**.

Comment: Es posible que los errores sean minoría. ¿Es este uno de esos casos minoritarios? Si es así solucionémoslo. Si te he entendido bien tu piensas que el motivo de cierre es incorrecto.

Comment: Lo que yo pienso es que no hay recursos suficientes en la comunidad para analizar y solucionar cada caso puntual. Cada uno de nosotros puede, si lo desea, mejorar los criterios con los que vota, **pero no hay forma de obligarlos**. También creo que no hay una persona que tenga la razón absoluta a la hora de decidir si un cierre es correcto o no (o su motivos). Mi impresión es que cada vez hay más usuarios que votan y que eso ayuda a la comunidad. De la misma manera, creo que el número de usuarios que llegan compensan con creces a los usuarios que abandonan el sitio por cierres incorrectos.

Comment: Ya que piensas que "El cierre es correcto, en mi opinión, aunque tal vez no tanto el motivo". ¿Cual crees que es el motivo de cierre correcto?

Comment: No estoy tan seguro de que todos revisen las preguntas con un criterio concienzudo antes de hacer "click" en el botón cerrar. Soy relativamente nuevo en esSO, he planteado dos preguntas más que por ignorar la respuesta con el ánimo de enriquecer el contenido y las dos, antes de las dos horas estaban marcadas para ser cerradas: una porque era supuestamente un duplicado (y claramente no lo era, lo reconoció el autor mismo del supuesto duplicado) y la otra por ser demasiado amplia (cuando estaba preguntado 3 cosas sobre jQuery 3). Esa actitud empobrece seriamente a esSO. Saludos.

Comment: "¿Cual crees que es el motivo de cierre correcto?" Demasiado amplia. Existen muchas formas de codificar lo que el OP indica. No habría manera de escoger una verdadera e imparcial respuesta correcta.

Comment: @Mendoza, ¿Algo tan sencillo de resolver como "contar cuantas veces aparece cada dígito en un número" te parece muy amplio? ¿Que debes pensar entonces de [How to count each digit in a range of integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059680/how-to-count-each-digit-in-a-range-of-integers) ? Esa otra pregunta, con +47/-0 en el sitio inglés incluye a esta pregunta "tan amplia" y requiere de todavía más cosas para ser resuelta.

Answer (score 6):

## Respuesta parcial

> ¿Vamos a negar la posibilidad de preguntar al que no sabe nada?

No deberíamos.

> ¿Le vamos a cortar las alas antes de que empiece a volar?

No deberíamos.

> Y luego está la cuestión de la respuesta... ... Pero también es posible dar una respuesta indirecta...

En otros sitios de SE se permite dar respuestas parciales, o indirectas como le llama Jose Antonio, el OP. En mi opinión deberíamos permitirlo y alentarlo, pero otra cuestión, es que hacer si alguien mas responde de "forma directa pero perjudicial", es decir, proporciona código listo, para sólo copiar y pegar sin dar explicación. En este caso opino que debería votarse negativamente a la respuesta.

## Argumentación parcial

En contraste a [Preguntas de hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado/), esta pregunta se refiere a que el cerrar las preguntas básicas es una forma de maltrato, contrario a la [política de comportarse bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) de SOes, más a específicamente a (énfasis mío):

> 2. Se acogedor, paciente, y de buenas intenciones. No esperes que los nuevos usuarios conozcan todas las reglas, porque no todos las conocerán. Y **tenles paciencia en lo que van aprendiendo**. Si estás aquí para ayudar, hazlo lo más simple posible para que otros también te puedan ayudar. Aquí todos somos voluntarios, y nadie responde bien a las demandas de ayuda.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo Rubén, no se trata de negar ayuda a los nuevos usuarios, al contrario indicarles el procedimiento y la forma para responder/preguntar. El sitio no es un foro para realizar preguntas abiertas (recorde yahoo answers hehe), existen reglas.

Comment: En ocasiones parece que se intenta reinventar la rueda cuando esta discusión sobre este tipo de preguntas ya se realizo.