# Cierre de preguntas conceptuales

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-de-cierre, votos-de-reapertura

He notado que en el sitio las preguntas sobre conceptos no son muy bien recibidas. En lo personal, creo que son las preguntas más interesantes porque invitan a entender cómo funcionan las cosas.

Nombraré 2 ejemplos recientes:
*(Pero quiero dejar constancia, que no son los únicos 2 casos que he visto)*.

**1.- [Div vs Span, cuando se utiliza uno u otro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/576320/div-vs-span-cuando-se-utiliza-uno-u-otro)**

Esta pregunta fue cerrada, pero luego fue vuelta a hacer casi idénticamente:

- [div vs span, ¿cuándo utilizar uno u otro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/576465/div-vs-span-cu%c3%a1ndo-utilizar-uno-u-otro)

Teniendo actualmente 2 votos de cierre, pero como no logró cerrarse a tiempo pudo lograr tener nada menos que 5 respuestas, además de votos positivos tanto en la pregunta y como en las respuestas.

Además me causa extrañeza que uno de los usuarios que cerró la primera, respondió la segunda

**2.- [Alguien me explica para qué sirven los getters, los setters, y las clases abstractas en TypeScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/576734/301324)**

Casualmente son los mismos usuarios que cerraron la pregunta anterior. En esta última podría estar de acuerdo ya que son 2 preguntas en una. Pero de todas maneras entiendo que el enfoque de la pregunta es a la utilización de elementos como `get`, `set` y `abstract` que no ve sentido en ellas. Y repito, que si bien creo que lo mejor hubiera sido 2 preguntas separadas, igualmente es lo suficientemente acotada para ser respondida.

---

A causa de esto, veo un problema con los votos de cierre y reaperturas, porque la primera pregunta (que fue cerrada) yo voté por la reapertura y aun cuenta con ese único voto, pero cuando se hizo nuevamente tuvo 5 respuestas.

Entonces:

- Las preguntas antes mencionadas están bien cerradas o no?
- Se está visitando poco las colas de reapertura?

Por último no quiero dejar de mencionar un patrón que he visto. Es que preguntas que ponen 20 mil líneas de código y que no son imposibles de reproducir de ninguna manera se mantienen siempre abiertas. Este tipo de preguntas, a mi parecer, si bien son válidas son las que menos aportan, ya que las respuestas solo sirven a un único usuario, pues su caso es irreproducible. Pero aun así somo más indulgentes con ellas.

Lo que me lleva a mi 3ra pregunta:

- No se estará votando el cierre por la extensión de la pregunta??? Es decir, "se pesan" en vez de analizarlas y juzgarlas en su justo mérito y relevancia

*Nota aclaratoria: Entiendo que en la mayoría de los casos, una pregunta de un par de líneas es una mala pregunta (es cosa de revisar la cola), pero no vaya a ser que se haya convertido en un acto reflejo el cerrarlas sin antes analizarlas.*

Comment: la primera está basada en opiniones... yo uso div para grillas y spam para contenido no relevante ... cada quien puede tener una opinión distinta ... solo mira los framework de diseños y veras que no llegan a una conclusión precisa de cuando usar que cosa ... y eso no incluso no lo hace canónico.

Comment: la segunda pregunta carece de investigación la implementación de getter y setter va acompañada de oop y de MVC o algunos patrones de diseño/arquitectura de software para facilitar las pruebas unitarias, el debug por otros medios y el mantenimiento de la aplicación ... el principio de atomicidad es importante que se aplique.

Comment: Por lo tanto están muy bien cerrada las dos preguntas; detrás de las preguntas que tu calificas como conceptuales hay un sin fin de conjeturas... o de esfuerzo que el OP no quiere hacer.

Comment: en cuanto a tu tercera pregunta: yo evaluó las preguntas antes de cerrarla o emitir votos de cierre y estoy casi seguro que la mayoría lo hace... si hay algunos que pasan de leer toda la pregunta por qué en algún punto ya detentan suficientes carencias que las hace candidatas para más de un motivo de cierre incluso.

Comment: En cuanto a las preguntas con 20 mil líneas de código que se mantienen abiertas como esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/576020/indexeddb-no-se-lleva-con-javascript-no-recoje-datos-includes-no-existe que es mía. Está bien argumentada... y si no la han cerrado es por dos motivos, el que tiene el privilegio de cierre no lo ha hecho porque sabe que no tiene el tiempo para verificar todo el contenido o la han evaluado y han determinado de que es cumple con lo mínimo para estar en el sitio.

Comment: Por lo tanto no estoy de acuerdo con tu publicación de meta. En este caso dejare mi voto negativo simbólico que expresa que estoy en desacuerdo. Saludos hermano.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Discrepo en el tema de cierres de preguntas. La primera puede y fue contestada 5 veces y todas las respuestas son en esencia son la misma, lo que me lleva a concluir que no es para nada basada en opiniones. La 2da pregunta tú dices que carece de investigación, pero teniendo en cuenta que si todos investigaran a fondo no existirían preguntas en el sitio, es que debe haber un margen, para mi es que el OP tenga el conocimiento necesario para entender la respuesta, en este caso el OP entiende el get/set más no su utilidad.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Preguntas de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado)

Comment: las 5 respuestas tienen implementaciones distintas, que solo arrojan una opinion personal de como lo haria cada usuario en particular (parecidas) ... eso no responde la pregunta de manera objetiva ... siguen siendo sugerencias y opiniones; y las sugerencias y opiniones son mal recividas en el sitio.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Tu link no responde para nada mi pregunta. Esa pregunta se refiere a preguntas del tipo "trabajo escolar" no a una duda conceptual, ambos casos son muy distintos. Por otro lado las 5 respuesta responden lo mismo, si fuera subjetivo habría otras opiniones; además se ha referenciado en al menos 3 respuestas a documentación oficial y es que no hay nada de subjetivo en él tema. Pero no solo eso es que además según la ayuda: "Algunas preguntas subjetivas están permitidas...Se espera que todas las preguntas subjetivas sean constructivas"

Comment: Super en desacuerdo con @ArcanisGK507 acá. QUe él use una etiqueta de una forma no tiene nada que ver con la documentación o el sentido semántico de cada etiqueta. Que la pregunta requiera ampliación y esfuerzo no significa que esté basada en opiniones

Answer (score 5):

Hay preguntas conceptuales bien recibidas y con excelente puntuación, como [¿Qué es la memoización y como se usa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398370/qu%C3%A9-es-memoizaci%C3%B3n-y-c%C3%B3mo-se-usa/398371#398371), así que el problema no es "lo conceptual".

**Div vs Span**

La pregunta "Div vs Span" es legitima, pues la respuesta será una lista de pros y cons de cada uno. Eso ayudará al programador a elegir correctamente.

El problema es que el OP no demuestra esfuerzo alguno. Una simple consulta a Google "Div vs Span" genera página tras página de información. Si nada de eso le sirvió, al menos podría contarnos porque. Si él no se esfuerza, nosotros tampoco.

**Getter y setter**

La pregunta sobre getter y setter es inapropiada: no busca la solución a un problema sino que le hagan clases a su medida. SOes no es una escuela de programación ni un servicio de tutoría. Esos son conceptos que debe aprender y estudiar en su carrera.

Sería distinto si estuviera entrampado en un código que usa setters y getters. Sabríamos con quién tratamos y sería más fácil explicar el enfoque correcto, pero no es el caso de esta pregunta.

**Preguntas largas**

Respecto a las preguntas "largas", me limito a señalar que el estándar es el "ejemplo mínimo, completo, reproducible". Las preguntas largas tienden a ser confusas y de mala calidad; no es grato trabajar en ellas. No las voto para cerrar; las evito. Supongo que a muchos les pasa lo mismo.

Comment: No me queda clara tu postura en `Div vs Span`, según tu opinión debe cerrarse o no?

Comment: @Yussef. Debe cerrarse pues "necesita detalles y aclaraciones": que investigó, que obtuvo, porque no le sirve.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto pero no lo comparto, la falta de esfuerzo es motivo de voto negativo no de cierre.

Comment: Por otro lado hay un tema de criterio disimiles que no logro asimilar ya que me señalas que el problema no es "lo conceptual" y colocas el ejemplo de `memoización` la cual no tiene código, tampoco demuestra esfuerzo y también la respuesta está en Google. Incluso bajo mi criterio, que es mucho más laxo que el tuyo, esa pregunta debía haberse cerrado porque es imposible de responder por alguna otra persona que no seas tú mismo. En cambio, las 2 preguntas que presento son perfectamente "respondibles" por cualquiera

Comment: @Yussef no se cerro por falta de esfuerso; se cierra por que no cumple lo minimo para estar en el sitio y por no demostrar interes; y se cierra para esperar que el OP edite su pregunta y la haga legible para la comunidad ... si eso no se cumple es por que el OP no tiene interes en aprender solo busca que le hagan la tarea... en ese caso se queda cerrada y el mismo sistema la manda a las profundidades para que otros no piedan tiempo viendo preguntas mal hechas ... control de calidad ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 para no enredar la discusión: 1) Yo no dije que se haya cerrado por falta de esfuerzo, yo contra argumentaba a Candid, y es si fuera por él las mantendría cerradas por este motivo. 2) Dejemos de hablar de "tareas", en mi opinión cuando hablamos de "tareas" tiene la connotación de un "deber" de que alguien te la mando a hacer, y no estamos en este caso.

Comment: Aquí, cuando se dice que "piden que les hagan la tarea", nos referimos a una persona que, sea un encargo de una escuela o de una empresa o simplemente un deseo, da a entender que quiere algo resuelto sin esperar nada a cambio ni haber hecho algun intento por resolverlo. Aquí, la persona que no demuestra que hizo un esfuerzo, nos trae la incertidumbre de si se esforzó o no. Y queremos evitar esa incertidumbre.