# Porque algunos de los usuarios más "veteranos", y algunos de los moderadores, no respetan las normas del sitio?

Tags: discusión, moderadores, usuarios

Hace muchos años, Serrat cantaba **"*harto ya de estar harto, ya me cansé*"**.
Así me siento, si, soy viejo y me canso pronto.
Hay mucha intolerancia con los "nuevos", **"Como se atreven a desconocer las normas si recién ingresan??!!"**.
Es patético, me molesta, y para más **"INRI"**, aquellos que dicen hacer cumplir las normas del sitio... **ni las han leido**!.

La mayoría de las preguntas que "molestan", son formuladas por usuarios nuevos... **ningún recien llegado lee el recorrido**, aceptenlo, puede gustarnos o no, pero es la realidad, es nuestro trabajo (autoimpuesto), ir formándolos para que vayan mejorando la calidad de sus preguntas, y no con votos negativos (que están desaconsejados por el sitio), sino con los comentarios, que dicho sea de paso, están para eso, y no para responder preguntas como hacemos varios de nosotros.

Voy a exponer algunas de las normas que considero más importantes y más ultrajadas (las negritas son mías).

sacado de:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values -> 1. Las personas primero:

- Relaciones grupales - Cómo nos tratamos los unos a los otros es la clave para el éxito. La meta principal es crear y apoyar a la comunidad. El resto vendrá solo.
- Cualquier interacción en el sitio empieza por el respeto mutuo hacia nuestros compañeros, independientemente de las circunstancias, reputación, conocimiento u otras cosas.
- En nuestra comunidad, **todo el mundo se siente cómodo y bienvenido cuando preguntan, responden o comentan**.

---- Esto invitaría a abandonar las acusaciones del tipo **"usas chatNoseque"**, **"no hacemos tutorias"** y otras por el estilo, que son bastante ultrajantes. ----

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour -> Mejora las publicaciones mediante ediciones o comentarios:

- Recuerda: Todos estamos aquí para aprender; así que, **sé amable** y ayuda a los demás.
- Utiliza los comentarios para pedir más información o para aclarar una pregunta o respuesta.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down ->

- Utiliza tu voto negativo cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o respuesta **atrozmente descuidada, poco rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo empleado**, o que es clara, pero quizás **peligrosamente incorrecta**.

---- Acá me permito hacer una acotación sobre **"sin ningún esfuerzo empleado"**, toda respuesta exige un esfuerzo, y si observamos las otras reglas que acompañan esta afirmación, veremos que estamos hablando de cosas "graves", no votemos negativo por esto (en lo que sigue, veremos que a veces las normas del sitio son contradictorias). ----

- El privilegio de voto positivo viene primero, porque es en lo primero que debes concentrarte: mover el contenido de calidad a la parte superior. **El voto negativo debe reservarse para casos extremos**. No es un sustituto de la comunicación y la edición.
- **En vez de votar negativo:** Si el mensaje es spam u ofensivo, repórtalo. Si la pregunta es duplicada o no relacionada a la temática del sitio, repórtala para la atención de un moderador. Si algo está equivocado, por favor añade un comentario o edita la publicación para corregirlo.

https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour -> Obtén respuestas para preguntas prácticas y detalladas -> No preguntes sobre:

- Cosas que no hayas buscado una solución (¡muestra tu trabajo!)
- Enunciados de ejercicios, sin demostrar que se intentó resolver el ejercicio (no alcanza con escribir una línea de código, ¡demuestra tu trabajo!)

---- Segunda acotación, hay preguntas que no ameritan mostrar nada, **el que pregunta no sabe**, y a veces ese "no se", hace imposible presentar nada (ver ejemplo al final). Ahora bien, soy consciente que no hay que contestar preguntas del tipo "tengo que hacer esto... hazlo" (aunque me sigo equivocando), un problema es la delgada linea que separa estas de las que, por ejemplo, un usuario dice "me quede atorado y no se como hacer esto, el otro, es la mala praxis de un/algunos/los moderador/es, que cierran preguntas que no ameritan ser cerradas, y eso me impulsa a contestar rápido, para llegar antes del cierre y que el usuario pueda llevarse algo. ----

Y hablando de nuestros queridos moderadores...

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions -> ¿Por qué algunas preguntas están marcadas "en espera"?:

Las preguntas que necesitan trabajo adicional o que no encajan en este sitio pueden ser puestas en espera por miembros experimentados de la comunidad. Mientras las preguntas estén en espera, no pueden ser respondidas, pero pueden ser editadas para hacerlas elegibles para reapertura. Si tu pregunta se ha puesto en espera, recibirás feedback privado sobre las razones por la que se marcó así.

Las preguntas que son editadas dentro de cinco días de haber sido puestas en espera son automáticamente agregadas a una cola de reapertura a revisión de la comunidad. Las preguntas que no sean reabiertas dentro de los cinco días cambiarán de [en espera] a [cerrada]. Las preguntas en espera también pueden ser nominadas para ser reabiertas por usuarios con suficiente reputación. Si suficientes usuarios concuerdan, la pregunta se abrirá y podrá aceptar respuestas.

- Fuera de tema - cada comunidad decide cuáles temas específicos son y no son permitidos en su sitio. Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación dentro del alcance definido por la comunidad.

---- Puedo hacer una lista de no menos de diez preguntas válidas, que fueron marcadas como fuera de tema (en los últimos 40 días). ----

- Se necesitan detalles o más claridad - algunas veces necesitamos más información para ayudar a resolver tu problema.

---- Otra largan lista, es verdad que algunas preguntas requieren bastante esfuerzo para entender lo que se pide, pero si ya hay alguien que respondió... es que **no eran imposibles de entender**, dejen que los que tienen más ganas, trabajen. ----

---- Hoy cerró/cerraron una pregunta a los **siete minutos** de ser realizada... es una carrera?, gana el que cierra más?. ----

Preguntas en espera / cerradas:

- Si la pregunta no es reabierta en de cinco días, el aviso de [en espera] cambiará automáticamente a [cerrada].

---- Si como me imagino (ya que las preguntas no pasan por "en espera"), la opción "en espera", no está disponible, deberían dar un margen de algunos días (los 5 estipulados para "en espera"?), para dar chance al usuario (solo a los nuevos), para editar la misma, ya que es muy chocante para alguien que recien entra al sitio, y desconoce todas las normas el mismo, encontrarse con un "cerrada", invita a irse. ----

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators ->

- Gran parte del trabajo de moderación es bastante mundano: borrar spam obvio, **cerrar preguntas descaradamente fuera de tema**, y sacrificar algunas de las publicaciones **peor valoradas en el sitio**. El moderador ideal hace lo mínimo posible, pero sus acciones son poderosas, visibles, y altamente concentradas.
- Siempre que sea posible, **intente dejar comentarios frecuentes en las publicaciones en las que haya realizado (o considerado realizar) una acción de moderador**, explicando el razonamiento. Esto es importante para que los miembros de la comunidad puedan aprender las normas de la comunidad y las políticas de moderación.

Acá esta el ejemplo de pregunta al que hice referencia más arriba.

Hace poco formulé la siguiente pregunta, **"como le pido al sistema la altura de la barra de titulos"**, rápidamente apareció quien me pedía que muestre lo que había intentado... pensé en subirle las más de 7000 lineas de código de mi programa, después me vi tentado a escribir:

```
    alturaDeLaBarra = sistemaQueridoDameLaAlturaDeLaBarraOTeHagoUnBucleInfinito();
```

No quise generar discordia, asi que subí una parte de mi código... bien larga, que no compilaba, que no aportaba nada, ya que la respuesta, era **usa Insets**... y no la dió el que me cuestionó.

Final, como verán, esto tiene encabezado de pregunta y no lo es, es un llamado a la reflexión... ***y no va a faltar quien vote negativo y/o vote por el cierre*** jaja.

Agregado: tal vez no quedo claro cual es mi gran inquietud, **los usuarios nuevos se sienten atacados/expulsados**, que a mi me voten negativo, me molesta, pero no me afecta.
Si alguno miró mi perfil, sabe que hace más de cinco años que me registré, hace poco más de un mes y medio, que empecé a participar, y esto tiene sus razones.
Hace algo así como cinco años, con otra cuenta, entré a este sitio he hice una pregunta, muy tonta, muy de principiante, de esas que se pueden contestar sin que haga falta mostrar un código, la típica pregunta sobre una función del lenguaje, **porque *a = char( 128 )* me devuelve error**, me saltaron al cuello, **subi tu código**, **mostranos lo que has intentado**, bla bla bla, me fuí sin una respuesta (no necesito aclarar que la respuesta era que char va de 0 a 127).
Pasó mucho tiempo hasta que volví, no me olvido de la sensación, y veo repetirse la historia en carne de otros, bajo la bandera de "hacemos respetar las normas del sitio", algunos las trasgreden, copié algunas de las normas y agregué los enlaces, es por si alguno pecaba de simple desconocimiento, con los demás, no tengo chance, aquel que sabe que el sitio dice, por ejemplo, **votar negativo solo en casos extremos**, y le pone negativo a cualquier cosa... no tiene remedio, espero que los otros inclinen la balanza.

Agregado 2: cuando volví, evité formular preguntas, solo me dediqué a responder, en una semana, acumulé negativos que me bloquearon la posibilidad de contestar... respuesta correctas vistas desde la programación, pero que carecían de explicación... ninguno de los que me votó negativo, me ayudó con un comentario, la suerte quiso que el mismo día que me bloquearon, mientras tomaba la decisión de no volver nunca más, alguien aceptó una de mis respuestas, días después, un buen usuario me comentó, **tu respuesta es solo código, carece de explicación**... era tan fácil.

Comment: Ojo.. esto es meta, y aca los votos son en contra o a favor de lo que postulas... no sobre la pregunta en si... si la gente esta de acuerdo, te vota positivo, si esta en desacuerdo, te vota negativo...

Comment: **ningún recien llegado lee el recorrido, aceptenlo, puede gustarnos o no, pero es la realidad** Resp: Te guste o no, el sistema no es una democracia, aqui el que tiene más reputacion puede hacer con sus privilegios lo que mejor le plasca y si estan en desacuerdo puedes reportarlo a un moderador ... si crees que tienes las pruebas para corroborar lo que te este moletando, adicional esos recien llegados como lo dices, por no saber las normas hacen preguntas, que no cumplen con los estandares de calidad y por ende son cerradas y eliminadas. **te guste o no**

Comment: No logro encontrar la idea central en esta publicación. Aborda diversos temas sin llegar a ninguna proposición concreta.

Comment: Lo que si te recomiendo: si ves que un usuario no respesta las normas, por favor reportalo. Si ves que uno de nosotros, los moderadores diamantados, no respeta las normas, por favor, entra al chat y trata de comunicarte con otro. Si piensas que los moderadores estamos cometiendo faltas graves, siempre puedes comunicarte con un CM de la compañia para reportarnos.

Comment: Publicación desviada... Titulo habla de usuarios no respetando las normas del sitio, y no se habla nada de eso. Al final rematas con: "Hice una publicación y paso esto...". Te faltaba un MRE y no te lo han explicado bien, eso si estaba mal.

Comment: sentido comun: el usuario [Ruslan López](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/342/ruslan-l%c3%b3pez) con 7 años de experiencia en el sitio y 11K de puntos de reputacion te indica que es conveniente agregar que has intentando por 3 motivos: 1) hay muchas formas de hace lo que quieres. 2) que demuestres cual de esas muchas formas has intentado para tener un punto de partida para quien te quiera dar una respuesta. 3) por que es necesario segun la norma del sitio ... que te hace pensar que un usuario con 479pt de reputacion es la excepcion a la regla????

Comment: creo que tienes la suficiente edad y reputacion para saber que existe el [CHAT de SOes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) si entraras aqui y preguntaras por que alguien hizo XYZ Comentario/Acciones en un post te aseguro que alguien te dara una explicacion ... en tu post siento ira, odio, frustracion ... pero en lugar de solicitar orientacion has creado un post en el cual recibiras votos negativos por que la mayoria no comparte tu sentimiento u opinion.

Comment: @gbianchi, primer comentario totalmente de acuerdo, segundo comentario, **no se quien vota negativo, no se quien cierra respuestas validas**, elaboré una lista con las preguntas cerradas que no debían ser cerradas, y otra con votos negativos sin razón de ser, las hice para solicitar la intervención desde "arriba"... pero desistí, primero quiero intentar por la vía difícil.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, ***aqui el que tiene más reputacion puede hacer con sus privilegios lo que mejor le plasca***, esto deja claro tu postura, te importan un bledo las normas, con que criterio después dices **esos recien llegados como lo dices, por no saber las normas... blabla**.

Comment: Con respecto al comentario de Ruslan López, tanto tú como el deberían leer las normas del sitio, especificamente donde dice, **no todas las preguntas ameritan presentar el código creado**, y no, no hay muchas formas de hacerlo, de hecho solo hubo una respuesta, es una pregunta concreta sobre una función concreta del lenguaje, que yo desconocía... **si la desconozco, que podría haber intentado?**.

Comment: @CandidMoe, la idea central es bien simple, me tomé el trabajo de subir las indicaciones que da el sitio, tanto para usuarios como para moderadores... las han leído, esto todo lo que puedo hacer, el resto que da en cada uno de ustedes, podemos hacer de este lugar un campo de espinas para los usuarios nuevos o no.

Comment: @Excorpion, dices **Titulo habla de usuarios no respetando las normas del sitio, y no se habla nada de eso**, cuando pongo las referencias a cuando votar negativo, estoy hablando de que muchos usuarios  bien desconocen cuando hacerlo, o bien se defecan en las normas del sitio.

Comment: Voy a seguir borrando comentario si no se mantiene una charla civilizada. Dejen los comentarios personales para otro lado.

Comment: @gbianchi, perdón, no creo haberme salido de lo "correcto", pero voy a hacerlo mejor, gracias por llamarme al orden.

Comment: @MarcePuente Votar negativo es un privilegio, es algo que no todos hacen. Si lo hacen, es por que creen necesario marcarlo como "malo". No te están dando negativos de gratis si tu crees eso.

Comment: @Excorpion, no se trata de mi, me pueden votar negativo todo lo que quieran, se trata del usuario nuevo, que recién ingresa al sitio, hace una pregunta y lo llenan de votos negativos, algunos "justificados", otros arbitrarios, termina cerrada la pregunta y la sensación... es de que te expulsan, yo quiero terminar con eso, hace cinco años, con otra cuenta hice una pregunta... tarde cinco años en volver al sitio y preguntar.

Comment: Este tipo de publicaciones en meta son realizadas regularmente por usuarios que generalmente son nuevos y tienen "ideas nuevas" sobre temas que ya fueron platicados anteriormente, por eso me llama mucho la atención tu publicación, ya que eres miembro del sitio desde hace 5 años y 9 meses. Simplemente, hay que seguir las reglas, tal vez muchos usuarios nuevos no las conocen, por eso hay que ayudarles a realizar publicaciones que ayuden a tener una buena calidad de la información en el sitio.

Comment: Dos cosas, hace cinco años que me registre, hace un mes y medio que participo, si lees mi publicación, verás que justamente me tomé el trabajo de subir los links de lo que dice el sitio acerca de los temas que expuse, no son mis opiniones, son las directivas del sitio, que parecen ser desconocidas por muchos... o decididamente descartadas.

Comment: Conozco la sensación que mencionas @MarcePuente, pero no es empatía lo que se busca tener acá. Hay determinadas reglas las cuales leer, otros usuarios como yo, damos aviso primero antes de votar negativo, o votar para cerrar una publicación. Además de que hay que mantener el sitio limpio, y en regla, los moderadores estan cargados, por lo que el resto nos encargamos de solventar lo demás. Si algo no te parece, esta bien, pero a menos que tengas pruebas, o un reporte que hacer contra X usuario, estos son libres de usar y gastar sus puntos para votar negativo, cerrar post, o lo que quieran.

Comment: @Excorpion, y yo soy libre de seguir quejándome de los usuarios que no se manejan como tu, si tu puedes entenderlo, los demás debieran entenderlo.

Comment: Obvio, te puedes quejar, eso mismo es lo que dije, y lo repito, si tienes pruebas contra X usuario, repórtale, que está bien que la gente reporte y se preocupe de los demás.

Comment: @Excorpion, lamentablemente no puedo saber quien vota, ni quien cierra preguntas.

Comment: @MarcePuente Puedes reportar la publicación como tal, y el moderador sabrá que revisar. Y cuando adquieras mas privilegios, puedes llegar a hacer lo mismo tu.

Comment: @Excorpion, gracias, no sabía... y no creo vivir tantos años. jaja.

Comment: jajajaja no pasa nada, algunos llegan, otros no

Comment: Igual me gustaría teneer el nivel de algunos de ustedes!!!... y menos años!!!

Comment: todavia sigo esperando que este señor demuestre como es que yo no sigo las normas del sitio...

Answer (score 10):

Vamos por partes

---

> Hay mucha intolerancia con los "nuevos"

En realidad, tenemos (a excepción de contados usuarios) mucha paciencia con los nuevos. Tanto, que tenemos comentarios prefabricados con un tono neutro o incluso amable. Casi nunca vi mensajes agresivos, si no más bien sinceros y con la intención de orientar al OP a una mejor pregunta.

A veces, a veces se puede ver una pregunta que da a entender vagancia y/o falta de respeto, lo cual puede hacer explotar a algunos. Así que miralo un poco por nuestro lado.

---

> es nuestro trabajo (autoimpuesto), ir formándolos para que vayan
> mejorando la calidad de sus preguntas, y no con votos negativos (que
> están desaconsejados por el sitio), sino con los comentarios

En realidad, no es nuestro trabajo. A lo sumo, lo es moderar el sitio. Los que dejamos un comentario, lo hacemos por hacer entender al OP lo que sucede y es completamente opcional.

Los votos negativos NO están desaconsejados. Al contrario, se busca que la gente vote para regular las preguntas del sitio. Y si, yo soy del partido de que un voto negativo debe venir con explicación, pero la mayoría no quiere eso. Recuerda que es trabajoso ese aspecto.

Además, que pasa si los comentarios no funcionan, lo que pasa seguido? Y si el usuario trae más preguntas de baja calidad? Hay que regular eso de alguna forma.

---

> "no hacemos tutorias"

Yo uso eso (probablemente lo leiste de mí) para indicar una realidad. No es agresivo, mas bien es neutro y es una verdad. Algunos usuarios vienen en busca de que los guien a terminar un ejercicio, yo les indico que no están en el sitio adecuado.

---

> Segunda acotación, hay preguntas que no ameritan mostrar nada, el que
> pregunta no sabe, y a veces ese "no se", hace imposible presentar nada
> (ver ejemplo al final).

Pero, podés intentar algo, sea escribiendo código, o buscando en internet la solución, o debugueando.. A veces, es necesario mostrar el intento. Otras veces, parece que no es necesario. Sinceramente, aun no entiendo ese aspecto, pero son preguntas que si ameritan una respuesta.

---

> ---- Hoy cerró/cerraron una pregunta a los siete minutos de ser realizada... es una carrera?, gana el que cierra más?. ----

Sobre los puntos anteriores del centro de ayuda, no puedo decir nada por que no vi las preguntas mencionadas. Pero si sobre esto.

Cuanto más rapido es cerrada una pregunta de baja calidad, mejor. Antes, no pensaba así, hasta que alguien respondió una pregunta antes de que sea cerrada, perjudicando al OP haciendole la tarea y al sitio apoyando este tipo de preguntas.

No es una carrera, pero debe cerrarse lo antes posible.

---

> ya que es muy chocante para alguien que recien entra al sitio, y desconoce todas las normas el mismo, encontrarse con un "cerrada", invita a irse.

Si no leen la ayuda, no leen los links en los comentarios, se están negando a entender el funcionamiento del sitio y la comunidad, y por lo tanto malinterpretan que es que una pregunta esté "cerrada" y se van, no es nuestro problema. Además, una persona que no respeta a los usuarios del sitio y sus reglas de manera intencional, en mi opinión, no es bienvenido en el sitio. Es una persona egoista que solo quiere una respuesta.

---

> Hace poco formulé la siguiente pregunta, "como le pido al sistema la
> altura de la barra de titulos", rápidamente apareció quien me pedía
> que muestre lo que había intentado... pensé en subirle las más de 7000
> lineas de código de mi programa, después me vi tentado a escribir:
>
> ```
> alturaDeLaBarra = sistemaQueridoDameLaAlturaDeLaBarraOTeHagoUnBucleInfinito();  No quise
> ```
>
> generar discordia, asi que subí una parte de mi código... bien larga,
> que no compilaba, que no aportaba nada, ya que la respuesta, era usa
> Insets... y no la dió el que me cuestionó.

No subas ni el código completo, ni un fragmento de código. Esos no cumplen los requisitos de un [EMCV](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). En eso estoy de acuerdo en que deberían haberte pasado el link anterior, en lugar de simplemente pedir tu intento.

Un emcv hace nuestro trabajo mucho más facil.

No todos los que "cuestionan" (en realidad, están tratando de ayudar) saben siquiera sobre el lenguaje de programación que uses. Eso se debe a las [colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review). Los usuarios que se ofrecen para esto revisan preguntas que, si bien no sabrían responder, si sabrían orientar al usuario que la escribió a una pregunta de mejor calidad.
Además, considera que quizá no se podía sacar facilmente la conclusión que mencionas con el fragmento publicado.

Comment: también es impórtate acotar que aquellos usuarios que siente que no son bienvenidos son exactamente aquellos que no les interesa seguir las normas del sitio.

Comment: @DanteS, **miralo de nuestro lado**, estoy en el medio, si bien casi no hago preguntas, no me olvido de mis comienzos, de cuando no entendía nada, de cuando no sabía como buscar, como preguntar, si miras mi perfil, verás que hace años que estoy en el sitio, y solo un mes y medio participando, quieres saber porque, con otra cuenta, realicé una pregunta, muy sencilla, me saltaron al cuello... nunca más volví a preguntar... como dije por ahí arriba, ahora me pasa que a veces, respondo en los comentarios para evitar negativos y comentarios fuera de lugar (que desconocen las normas del sitio).

Comment: 1) **no es nuestro trabajo. A lo sumo, lo es moderar el sitio**, te estás contradiciendo, moderar el sitio implica enseñar a los usuarios a manejarse en el. 2) **Los votos negativos NO están desaconsejados**, segun el sitio:  **El voto negativo debe reservarse para casos extremos**.https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down, 3) **no hacemos tutorias** no eres el único que da respuestas de ese tipo... y si, son bastante agresivas, no hablo de tu intención (la desconozco), hablo de como se recibe, hay mejores formas de expresar lo mismo.

Comment: 4) **Pero, podés intentar algo, sea escribiendo código, o buscando en internet la solución**... esto es internet, este es un sitio de respuestas para programadores, es tan difícil de entender, puse como ejemplo mi caso, porque es bastante fácil entender lo imposible de mostrar *lo que he intentado* hasta jugando con la ironía, de un supuesto intento, **si no conozco un método no puedo intentar usarlo**.

Comment: 5)  **perjudicando al OP haciendole la tarea**, si o no, tanto tu como yo, como todos, hemos aprendido leyendo código... hecho por otros, si resuelvo un ejercicio y lo explico, no le hago daño al OP, si el no analiza el ejercicio, el se hace daño... no leo la mente, no trato de adivinar lo que va a hacer. 6) **Si no leen la ayuda, no leen los links ...... por lo tanto malinterpretan que es que una pregunta esté "cerrada" y se van, no es nuestro problema**, puede que no sea tu problema... es el mio, a mi me importa el que está buscando ayuda, aunque no entienda como funciona el sitio

Comment: como dije antes, empecé a participar hace un mes y medio, en una semana acumulé varios votos negativos, no se me permitía responder, quede aislado, los votos negativos fueron por repuestas "correctas" desde la programación, pero que carecían de explicación (nadie me dejo un comentario al respecto, solo los votos), por suerte alguien acepto una de mis respuestas... sino probablemente me hubiese ido. Con respecto a tu último comentario... lo entiendo, pero no comparto, si no se de un lenguaje, debería abstenerme.

Comment: @MarcePuente  una nota importante.. un intento, por ejemplo, es busque todo esto en google, y nada me sirviio.. eso es un intento mas que valido! pero, a veces ni eso demuestran unos usuarios... decir, lo busque.. no alcanza.. que buscaste??? o que intentaste buscar? a veces tambien se puede ayudar a mejorar los metodos de busqueda...

Comment: @gbianchi, yo no estoy en total desacuerdo con eso, lo que cuestiono, es las veces en las que no tiene sentido pedir eso e igual se lo pide (obrar sin aplicar en más mínimo criterio)... y siempre enfocado en los usuarios nuevos, y sobre todo en aquellos que recién empiezan,

Comment: Voy a ver si este comentario me permite abrir una sala de chat para responderte. Por que sería molesto que esta discusión larga inunde los comentarios.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142509/room-for-dante-s-and-marce-puente

Answer (score -1):

Probablemente seré el único que estará de acuerdo contigo (por lo menos en parte).

Como no hace mucho yo fui usuario nuevo, tengo aun patente que la acogida no fue de las mejores.

Cuando comencé en el sitio me agregaban comentarios a mis respuestas (con demasiada condescendencia para mi gusto) que me pedían que revisara un enlace y "bla bla bla"; yo iba a ese enlace y no leía nada que señalara que mi publicación era incorrecta. Y siempre me preguntaba ¿Habrán leído eso mismo que ellos me mandan a leer?

El asunto escaló hasta que lo discutimos vía chat, y ahí me señalaron que tenía que respetar **"las normas no escritas"**, ante tamaña razón decidí no seguir discutiendo el tema ese día. (y si no están escritas para que me mandan leer una página!!!)

Tal como tu señalas, la mayoría de usuarios que moderan no conocen las normas y si las conocen no las cumplen, y asumen una serie de normas de facto que ningún usuario nuevo puede conocer.

En algún momento conversé sobre esto, y pedí que si existe un consenso ya establecido, que esto se viera reflejado en el `help`. La respuesta es que la ayuda y las normas del sitio ya son lo suficientemente claras (no estoy de acuerdo)

El caso típico es el tema de demostrar esfuerzo. Según las normas, se requiere mostrar esfuerzo solo en trabajos **escolares** y un "Ejemplo Mínimo Completo y Verificable" solo cuando sea necesario (en especial los casos de depuración).

**No existe motivo de cierre para preguntas sin código, no obstante el poco esfuerzo en una publicación si es motivo de voto negativo.**

Pero el asunto no queda ahí, no vayas a cometer el error de responder una pregunta que no soporta los estándares de algunos, que por mucho que tu pregunta sea correcta e incluso aceptada, te pueden caer los negativos junto con comentarios pidiendo las explicaciones del por qué osaste responder una pregunta en un sito de preguntas y respuestas. Sobre una tema parecido di mi opinión [acá](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5480/301324) (no fue muy bien recibida)

Y a aquí viene una de las principales contradicciones, te dicen que debes responder no solo pensando en el autor de la pregunta, sino que también en las futuras personas que busquen el mismo problema. ¿Entonces, que importa el esfuerzo del autor?

Y para no extenderme no entraré en el tema del cierre por "basado en opiniones" que ahí también veo un abuso excesivo.

SOes va en camino a convertirse en una comunidad toxica, tal como pasó con SOen y al igual que pasó allá, la comunidad activa negaba este hecho hasta que fue demasiado tarde.

Para mí el problema radica en que muchos usuarios antiguos están hastiados, si navegas a las primeras preguntas aceptaban hasta "¿cómo cocinar un huevo?". Ahora cuando ellos tienen buen puntaje solo se dedican a moderar, y como dicen en mi país "no comen, ni dejan comer", y me consta que existen algunos usuarios intimidados a responder a causa de esto.

Me parece un error haber bajado a 3 votos el cierre, yo veo usuarios que su actividad es mayormente cerrar preguntas, en un sito de cierre de preguntas serían estrellas.

Finalizo con un ejemplo, la última pregunta cerrada a este momento
[¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los paquetes controller, services, repository y model en sprint boot?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/581057/301324)

No entiendo la razón, la cerraron por ser muy corta?

---

Por si alguien se confunde, yo no digo ni quiero que "todo valga", voto por cerrar muchas preguntas, porque francamente algunas son insalvables, del tipo "Ayer empecé un curso de programación, como podría desarrollar un sistema operativo ?" o los que pegan una foto de la tarea que consta de 14 puntos sobre listas enlazadas (este caso si es una tarea), o las indescifrables que ya han pasado por suficientes días  y no ha clarificado.

---

**UPDATE**

Para los que puedan ver publicaciones borradas:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581264/separar-los-pares-e-impares-de-un-array

Repaso lo acontecido

- Usuario nuevo hace una pregunta, la pregunta era el título de una tarea sin nada de código
- Lluvia de comentarios

  - Que hace el recorrido
  - Que te he votado negativo por...
  - Que busca en google (por 2 usuarios distintos)
- 3 Votos negativos
- Pregunta cerrada

Todo esto pasó en cosa de pocos minutos. No se le dio ni un tiempo de reacción al usuario, a mi casi me pareció un ataque coordinado, un poco más y lo pateamos en el suelo.

Finalmente el usuario si tenía código y si había intentado algo. Antes de ser borrada la publicación alcanzo a actualizarla y resulta que tenía un pequeño problema.

Debo aclarar que la pregunta de todas maneras iba a ser cerrada, porque el problema calificaba como error tipográfico, pero podría no haber sido el caso.

De todas maneras no era necesario bombardearlo a comentarios que no aportaban nada, con que le digan que haga el tour UNA vez basta y sobra. Y enviarlo a Google es una tontería para eso cerramos el sitio.

Los negativos sobraban absolutamente, cero empatía, cero ganas de ayudar al novato y cero criterio.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con tus afirmaciones. Las normas del sitio deberían ser más claras. Por eso, cuando dejo un comentario, opto más por publicaciones de meta que del centro de ayuda.

Comment: Sobre la condesendencia, es dificil decirle a alguien "esto es de baja calidad" sin ofender. Y más, cuando es muy frecuente. A la larga, después de ver usuarios que no entienden las normas del sitio y ser alguien que las entiende, claro que te agarra un sentimiento de superioridad que tratarás de ocultar.

Comment: Casi lloro de emoción, creo que es la primera vez que alguien está de acuerdo conmigo en META. En el tema de la condescendencia, para ser justo, es un problema mío, yo sentía que los mensajes eran forzadamente educados, casi robóticos, pero que en el fondo no tenían la intención de ayudarme sino de solo presentar que estaba equivocado (supuestamente). Pero desconocía que muchos de estos mensajes son colocados por el sistema cuando un usuario modera una publicación.

Comment: Ahora que me toca moderar a mí, yo borro estos mensajes automáticos e intento explicar con palabras "de calle" porque algo me parece incorrecto. Pero por sobre todo para el caso puntual del autor y bajo el contexto de su pregunta o respuesta, no un comentario genérico y a veces ambiguo

Comment: 1.1 Como comenté, este tipo de publicaciones en meta son realizadas regularmente por usuarios que generalmente son nuevos y tienen "ideas nuevas" sobre temas que se platicaron anteriormente. Con respecto a la pregunta que refieres:
1)El usuario que pregunta es nuevo, aún no ha leído [tour], es su primera pregunta y no demuestra investigación en su pregunta, lo cual es sugerido por las normas del sitio.

Comment: 1.2  2)El usuario que responde ha tenido 7 repuestas, de las cuales 6 han sido eliminadas por la comunidad o por el mismo, ya que no intentaban responder la pregunta o tenían errores, solo esta publicación dada como respuesta es la única que incluso tiene puntuación positiva. Hay que ayudar a usuarios como ellos a realizar publicaciones que ayuden a la calidad de información en el sitio, al inicio del sitio se realizaron publicaciones y respuestas de baja calidad, pero queremos por el bien de la comunidad que la información sea de ayuda a los usuarios actuales y futuros del sitio.

Comment: @Jorgesys No me cabe duda que este tipo de comentarios se debe repetir en el tiempo, razón por la cual se deberían tomar más consideración, hay algo que mejorar y no se ha mejorado. Es un hecho que tanto el OP de esta publicación (Marce Puente) y yo, tuvimos problemas como usuarios nuevos y no fue por no haber leído las normas y el recorrido. Tus propios comentarios, sobre el ejemplo que expuse, me dan la razón.  (cont)

Comment: No existe motivo de cierre "Falta de investigación" en cambio, si posicionas el cursor del mouse en el `down vote` aparece "Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación..", lo que me lleva a concluir que la falta de investigación es motivo de voto negativo mas no de cierre. Pero además, tus argumentos se refieren más a la calidad del usuario (que es nuevo) que a la pregunta misma, que es justamente el reclamo. No hace mucho leí una pregunta de un usuario con mucho puntaje, pregunta que a mi parecer no pasaba los estándares, pero nadie le dijo algo. En mi caso siento lo mismo...

Comment: Ahora que tengo más puntaje, la tasa de comentarios en contra de mis respuestas es bajísimo. No digo que sea lo más habitual, pero sí que existen muchos casos que la antigüedad o el puntaje del que publica es sopesado por sobre la calidad de la publicación. Cuando, en mi opinión personal, a los usuarios nuevos deberíamos permitir un margen mayor. El sitio se nutre y vive de las preguntas y respuestas, debería ser lo prioritario, no de cerrar publicaciones, pero hay usuarios que solo se dedican a ello.

Comment: Sobre tu edición: supongo que es normal, después de ver que en el 95% de preguntas de ese estilo, el OP ni siquiera se toma el trabajo de responder los comentarios. Pero, eso no es escusa para convertir la moderación en toxicidad. Es una pena que parte de la comunidad esté cegada al respecto.

Comment: **No existe motivo de cierre "Falta de investigación"** En realidad, existe, pero dice que debe ser dentro del sitio. Es una norma mal escrita.

Comment: @DanteS. No es la única vez que he visto exactamente lo mismo, donde el usuario después de pedirle código lo agrega y si tenía avances. Yo ni siquiera digo esperar días, pero un par de horas por lo menos, quizás hizo la pregunta fue al baño, y cuando volvió tenía 3 negativos y pregunta cerrada. Sobre los motivos de cierre, a mí me aparecen: Duplicada, Necesita detalles o aclaraciones, necesita ser más específica, basada en opiniones y de la comunidad: No reproducible+tipográfico , la de incluir código en caso de **depuración**, idioma, recomendaciones, otro sito y otros.

Comment: Y la sección de la ayuda que indica los motivos es https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions donde tampoco encuentro algo referente a la "Falta de investigación"

Comment: @DanteS., como bien dices sí existe el motivo de cierre sobre la falta de investigación, o al menos yo lo veo en el tour (posiblemente mal explicado), pero dice lo siguiente: **No preguntes sobre... Cosas que no hayas buscado una solución (¡muestra tu trabajo!)** al decir "que no hayas buscado una solución" yo entiendo que se refiere a que no hayas investigado y al lado izquierdo está lo siguiente: **Las preguntas que necesitan mejoras se pueden cerrar hasta que alguien las arregle.**

Comment: @Israel-ICM El centro de ayuda da a entender (al punto de casi decirlo) que la investigación es unicamente dentro del sitio.

Comment: @Israel-ICM Existen 2 formas de penalizar una pregunta, cerrándola o votándola negativamente. La falta de esfuerzo no aparece en la lista de razones de cierre y no aparece `help` que habla de los motivos de cierre, pero si aparece en el tooltip del voto negativo, y para mí eso es lo que se advierte en el `Tour`. Caso contrario no debería existir la posibilidad de votar negativo una pregunta, solo la opción cerrar.