# Propuesta: mejorar el centro de ayuda

Tags: discusión

**Nota** He hablado con algunos usuarios, y llegamos a la conclusión de que redacté de una forma poco agradable. Pido disculpas por cualquier ofensa, he vuelto a redactar la pregunta para transmitir correctamente mi propuesta.

He estado debatiendo y viendo una respuesta en la pregunta [Porque algunos de los usuarios más "veteranos", y algunos de los moderadores, no respetan las normas del sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5496/porque-algunos-de-los-usuarios-m%c3%a1s-veteranos-y-algunos-de-los-moderadores-no).

Y hemos llegado a la conclusión de que, si bien en algunos aspectos el OP se equivoca sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, tiene razón en, al menos, un aspecto:

- El centro de ayuda no está indicando correctamente las normas del sitio.

#### Analizando lo ya escrito en el centro de ayuda

###### ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?

Si bien, no vimos con esos usuarios con mucha exactitud, miré el centro de ayuda para profundizar y noté lo siguiente:

> Busca, e investiga ...y mantén un registro de lo que encuentres.
> Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del
> sitio, incluyendo en los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas o que no
> hayan ayudado pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es
> diferente del resto.

Esta sección, da a entender que la investigación a hacer se limita unicamente a buscar dentro del sitio. Es más, si presionas el link en "busca" te lleva a una guía para buscar **dentro del sitio**.

Pero tengo entendido que así no funciona la comunidad. Ya que, la mayoría de las veces, Si la respuesta se encuentra en google facilmente, la comunidad ha tratado estas preguntas como "sin investigación", incluso si la respuesta no está en el sitio.

> No todas las preguntas se benefician del código incluido. Pero si tu
> problema está en el código que haz escrito, deberías incluir una
> parte.

Poner una parte de tu código no cumple los requisitos de un Ejemplo Minimo, Completo y Verificable según lo indicado por el centro de ayuda propio y respuestas en meta. Propongo que esta parte enlace a una zona del centro de ayuda que se adentre a explicar que es un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable y, por supuesto, debemos hacer entender por que nos es tan importante ese detalle.

Si bien es cierto que esto se aclara más adelante, empezar con una afirmación así hace que el usuario crea que debe poner un fragmento de código. Y, por lo que he visto, incluso en comentarios y como persona que responde preguntas, un fragmento de código a veces no nos sirve.

###### Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

No veo muchos problemas aquí, pero vendría bien aclarar que, a pesar de la necesidad de que el ejemplo sea minimo, no implica que deba dejar de ser completo y verificable.

###### ¿Por qué algunas preguntas están marcadas "en espera"?

> Las preguntas que necesitan trabajo adicional o que no encajan en este
> sitio pueden ser puestas en espera por miembros experimentados de la
> comunidad.

No conozco esa funcionalidad en el sitio. Todas las preguntas que vi y vote por cerrar tienen un aviso de "cerrada". Pero si esta funcionalidad existe, vendría bien que se comunicara explicitamente para que sea mejor entendido lo que sucedió con la pregunta.

#### Normas no escritas

A continuación, mencionaré las normas no escritas que llegué a entender que se me ocurrieron que podrían estar en el centro de ayuda:

- **No editar una publicación en otro idioma para traducirla, ese es trabajo del OP. Si publicas en ingles, podrías recibir votos negativos y de cierre.** He visto muchas preguntas que han terminado así.
- **(esto es mencionado parcialmente por el centro de ayuda, pero no es tan claro) No respondas preguntas de baja calidad, esto no es bien recibido por la comunidad y podría traerte votos negativos.** He visto comentarios y votos negativos cuando este escenario ocurre.
- **La investigación incluye "buscar en internet", no solo dentro del sitio.** Analizado más arriba.
- Algunas preguntas no requieren investigación (esto no me queda claro por que ni que criterio se sigue, quien quiera aclararlo, bienvenido sea). Me ha parecido ver alguna que otra con este caso, pero no estoy seguro, si no es el caso, se puede descartar.
- **Cuando te piden "lo que intentaste" en realidad se está pidiendo un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable o una lista de algunos de los links visitados.** Esto si es una semi-suposición, pero estoy muy seguro por los puntos anteriores.

#### Razones para mejorar el centro de ayuda

- Podría haber más usuarios que podrán entender el funcionamiento del sitio, por lo que la calidad, y por lo tanto el recibimiento, de sus publicaciones mejoraría. Esto también ayudaría a que menos usuarios nuevos terminen con cuentas bloqueadas.
- Lo anterior haría que el trabajo de revisión sea menos costoso, pues no tendrían primeras publicaciones que se basaron en una ayuda con conceptos errados.

---

#### Una alternativa

Si bien es cierto que estas normas si están escritas en meta (aunque no le pegué una leida profunda), dudo que un usuario nuevo se ponga a buscar estas publicaciones. Además, da la sensación de que poca gente (he mirado más de 21 preguntas en las colas de revisión) ha recomendado links a estas publicaciones en meta. Si no vamos a mejorar el centro de ayuda (lo cual quizá no es tan conveniente), **al menos, podríamos ayudar más a los ignorantes de las normas con links a las publicaciones en meta** y **también podríamos guiar mejor quitando los conceptos errados**.

No se las demás etiquetas, pero en la etiqueta Python, no veo que sean muy utilizados los links a meta. En ese caso, mi propuesta solo aplica a las etiquetas Python y las demás etiquetas donde estos links rara vez son utilizados.

#### Razones para mejorar los comentarios

- No llenaríamos el centro de ayuda con demasiada información
- Podríamos guiar al OP de una manera mas enfocada.

Comment: Hay un tema acá... Hay normas que no están escritas _en el Centro de Ayuda_, pero sí que lo están en Meta. Por ejemplo, lo de la traducción: [¿Qué hacer con las preguntas formuladas en inglés o en otro idioma?](/q/362)

Comment: El tema, es que nadie recomienda esos links ni están en el centro de ayuda. Ahora edito la pregunta.

Comment: Y otro enlace muy muy útil: el [FAQ](/q/1378).

Comment: Por otra parte, el año pasado en el chat destaqué la guía en [pt.so]: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/), que me pareció una joya.

Comment: Todos los enlaces que mencionas se vuelven inutiles si nadie los mira xD

Comment: Por último, que sí está en el Centro de Ayuda: [¿Qué pasa si necesito más ayuda?](/help/more-help). Eso por si quien busca algo no entiende el contexto de X situación. Y si no está en meta su duda/problema/pregunta, ahí sí, crear una nueva pregunta acerca de eso.

Comment: Entonces, dejamos toda la ayuda en manos de meta y dejamos también las equivocaciones? Para ese entonces, será demasiado tarde. Hasta que el usuario publica la pregunta (error que cometerá por las equivocaciones en la ayuda), recibe negativos, se la cierran, apenas terminó de leer la respuesta que le dice que pasó, y quizá ni eso.

Comment: Sabes lo poco que se necesita para perder el privilegio de publicar? y lo mucho que se necesita para recuperarlo? Un solo voto negativo es un riesgo inminente.

Comment: Además, tener una ayuda que no explica bien le da más trabajo a los revisores, por que se publican más preguntas de baja calidad.

Comment: no estoy de acuerdo ... las normas son generales ... y hay una amplia zona gris de trabajo ... meter más cosas al help center solo limitara más a los usuarios ... y provocara que el menú de cierre le comiencen a hacer falta cosas... y que en la cola de cierre se dé más trabajo ... todo esto tiene repercusiones que no les veo sentido ... basta con que todos los interesados comiencen a usar los link de los artículos en meta y que el OP sea coherente y se apegue a lo que indica la comunidad en sus comentario ya que cada Usuario/Pregunta/Respuesta es un mundo diferente que requiere adaptarse.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 antes de cuestionar, lee la pregunta con detenimiento. Los links en meta no sirven. Nadie los recomienda en comentarios al OP. Acabo de marcar en negro la parte que interesa. Por favor, lean la pregunta antes de votar y cerrar.

Comment: que te hace pensar que no la he leido... deja de faltar el respeto.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Lo que comentaste se centra en mi propuesta principal. No en mi propuesta secundaria. Propuse también usar los links en meta en comentarios.

Comment: Además, en mi pregunta anterior la volvieron a votar como duplicado. A pesar de la clara y razonable explicación que dejé diciendo que no lo era. Y si esa persona considera mi explicación no valida, estaría bueno que me explique por que.

Comment: *se apegue a lo que indica la comunidad en sus comentario* Los comentarios guian a un centro de ayuda que informa muy poco del funcionamiento de la comunidad.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 que te parece mi alternativa?

Comment: Perdon las ediciones, he clarificado más la pregunta y tenido en cuenta lo indicado.

Comment: @DanteS. en realidad sí se utilizan los enlaces relacionados en meta, otro tema es que sean _ampliamente utilizados_, eso sí. Varios usuarios suelen hacerlo, y los que más se suelen enlazar son: el relacionado a [los ingredientes de una buena pregunta](/a/4433), [por qué no compartir código como imagen](/a/3976), y por supuesto, los relacionados a [¿por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](/q/2868).

Comment: No pasa en Python. En Python, rara vez los vi enlazados, por no decir nunca. Sale otra edición!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los usuarios de Python no son los mismos que otros lenguajes  y no tratan a los nuevo igual ... por ejemplo en php somos muy detallistas al dar respuestas o hacer preguntas ... al igual que en javascript ... y a los usuarios nuevos les pedimos lo mismo...

Comment: Estoy tomandome el trabajo de revisar las colas de revisión y comprobar sus afirmaciones. Hasta ahora, revise más de 5 preguntas y ninguna usa enlaces a meta.

Comment: si tu estas en la tribu/feudo de python ... y vaz a ver la de php podras ver ciertas diferencias ...

Comment: incluso en php tenemos un feed especifico en un canal de chat para atender cualquier cosa que no se pueda por medio de preguntas en el sitio ...

Comment: Ya veo. Los canales de chat no funcionan con los más nuevos, por que se requiere minimo 20 de reputación.

Comment: Edité mi pregunta con el diagnostico

Comment: @DanteS. entra aqui: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142563/meta-dante

Comment: @padaleiana Es que las normas no deberían estar escritas en META, porque no podemos pretender que un usuario nuevo lea el tour, el help y todo META antes de realizar una pregunta, es de locos. Y luego porque lo que se diga en META es la opinión de un usuario, y aunque haya sido escrito por un CM diamantado full ultra power, que sabe el usuario nuevo de esto, uno ve que otro usuario igual que uno ha escrito su opinión y en general siempre hay otro usuario que comenta en contra, entonces a cual lee crees??

Comment: @Yussef concuerdo con lo que dijo Arkanis más arriba: _meter más cosas al centro de ayuda solo limitará más a los usuarios, y provocará que al menú de cierre le comiencen a hacer falta cosas, y que en la cola de cierre se dé más trabajo_. "No podemos pretender que un usuario nuevo lea el tour": Justamente es por eso que [es.so] es difícilmente un sitio al cual acudir _de emergencia_. No son muchos, pero varios se crean una cuenta aquí y luego de días (o semanas incluso) formulan una pregunta, conociendo bien el mecanismo del sitio, no _a ciegas_.

Comment: Por esa razón, debería darsele un uso a las publicaciones en meta en forma de comentarios (al menos, estaría  bueno que la comunidad en su totalidad los use). Pero de que sirve si la comunidad no tiene normas estrictas y nada está escrito en piedra?

Comment: @padaleiana Es que tal como hay que meter cosas hay que limpiar y fusionar otras, pero por sobre todo clarificar ciertos puntos. Te comento mi experiencia: Yo antes de responder me leí TODA la ayuda, luego entré a META y entendí (sobre todo por su nombre: "meta") que este sitio era para hablar del otro sitio. Pero también entendí que lo que se publica aquí son opiniones de usuarios, que aunque más veteranos, usuarios igual como lo soy yo; y por ejemplo con el tema de las tareas unos dicen no se deben responder otros decimos que depende de la pregunta, así te encuentras con opiniones distintas

Comment: Por ese motivo las reglas no pueden estar escritas aquí, porque no se entienden como reglas, se entienden como opiniones de usuarios. Y por ejemplo, para mí el tema del asunto del "Esfuerzo" es prioritario, si hay consenso que se debe mostrarlo que quede bien expresado y cerramos todas las preguntas que carecen de ello, pero en caso contrario que también quede expresado que hay casos donde no es necesario, hoy creo que es el mayor motivo de cierre.

Comment: @Yussef eso ya esta en meta: https://i.imgur.com/nKLRr3v.png claramente dice **Busca, e investiga ...y mantén un registro de lo que encuentres.** Entiendace que la comunidad (Usuarios) cuando le preguntan al OP **Que has hecho** es para que nos muestre un registro de lo que ha intentado ... para no desviarnos incluso poder educarlo y enseñarle como hacer busquedas/investigaciones más efectivas... te lo digo por que yo pase por el ARO .. odiava la documentacion por que pensaba que estaba mal escrita hasta que entendi que cada documentacion tiene un patron o diseño particular para cada lenguaje.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Creo que es justamente ese párrafo es a lo que se ha referido @Dante.S en muchos comentarios. Fíjate bien aparece "Busca" con un enlace a buscar en SOes, luego dice `... Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del **sitio**` por lo que habla de buscar solo en SOes no en otros medios, entonces yo infiero que ese párrafo apunta por sobre todo a no generar preguntas duplicadas, o en último caso que la sola presencia de un enlace a otra publicación de SOes ya mostraría el esfuerzo

Comment: No solo dicen eso, también el link "busca" arriba de todo dirije a una orientación para buscar en el sitio. Probablemente, este era el ideal inicial de SO, hasta que la comunidad cambió de rumbo sola. Como dice Yussef, esa parte está orientada a evitar duplicados, no a pedir que investigues en todo el internet.

Comment: @DanteS. desconosco si es un ejemplo o si es lo que espera el sitio... pero te aseguro que la comunidad ... incluyendome yo agradeceria cualquier cosa que agregue el usuario ... incluso si su recurso es externo...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Yo también. En principio, por como está diseñado el sitio, por que no me gusta ayudar a vagos y egoistas y por que quiero que aprendan a ser independientes, prefiero que las preguntas demuestren esfuerzo.