# Mejoras al Help Center (Detalles y Contenido)

Tags: característica-nueva, centro-de-ayuda

¿Estarías de acuerdo en hacer una revisión general del Centro de Ayuda? (por parte de los actuales miembros de la comunidad)

***Los objetivos serían:***
*1.- Agregar/actualizar conceptos nuevos que ayuden en la comprensión de las normas del sitio para usuarios nuevos y viejos.*
*2.- Eliminar conceptos ambiguos en pro de un lenguaje neutral consensuado por la comunidad.*
*3.- Agregar más detalles sobre qué espera la comunidad de los usuarios nuevos.*
*4.- Llevar al Centro de Ayuda contenido de algunas publicaciones en Meta con relativa importancia para la salud del sitio (o linkear directamente en los artículos del Centro de Ayuda aquellas publicaciones que hay en Meta que son de vital importancia para la comunidad).*

Comment: Y yo hago una propuesta similar y no recibo tan rapido los positivos. Y encima con negativos.

Comment: Yo no lo estoy haciendo por motivos personales .... lo estoy haciendo por que creo que hay muchas diferencia internas en la comunidad que pueden ser resueltas de esta manera ... siempre y cuando nos pongamos de acuerdo .... tal vez has mostrado algun motivo personal en tus argumentos y por ende no es neutral... si no la imposicion de tu perspectica/opinion personal.

Comment: No mostré ningún motivo personal ni imposición, quien crea eso, está equivocado. Pero tal vez el formato hubiera quedado mejor con una autorespuesta, por que quedó como imposición. Probaré copiando la publicación a ver que pasa.

Comment: @DanteS. Yo veo esta propuesta como la aceptación de la tuya, como que tus argumentos fueron convincentes para generar una  especie votación para llevarla a cabo

Comment: Si fuera así, hubieran votado positivamente mi propuesta, además de esta

Comment: Claro, quedó como imposición. No lo entendieron. Incluso, habiendo aclarado eso, siguen sin verlo como propuesta.

Answer (score 1):

**Nota** Esto no es una imposición ni está movido por motivos personales. Cualquier parecido a uno de estos es pura coincidencia.

Estoy de acuerdo. De hecho, hice una [propuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5499/158880) mencionando que cosas del centro de ayuda podrían ser mejoradas, aunque por alguna extrana razón tuvo un mal recibimiento. Aquí dejo una copia de la parte relevante de esa publicación:

###### ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?

###### ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?

Si bien, no vimos con esos usuarios con mucha exactitud, miré el centro de ayuda para profundizar y noté lo siguiente:

> Busca, e investiga ...y mantén un registro de lo que encuentres.
> Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del
> sitio, incluyendo en los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas o que no
> hayan ayudado pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es
> diferente del resto.

Esta sección, da a entender que la investigación a hacer se limita unicamente a buscar dentro del sitio. Es más, si presionas el link en "busca" te lleva a una guía para buscar **dentro del sitio**.

Pero tengo entendido que así no funciona la comunidad. Ya que, la mayoría de las veces, Si la respuesta se encuentra en google facilmente, la comunidad ha tratado estas preguntas como "sin investigación", incluso si la respuesta no está en el sitio.

> No todas las preguntas se benefician del código incluido. Pero si tu
> problema está en el código que haz escrito, deberías incluir una
> parte.

Poner una parte de tu código no cumple los requisitos de un Ejemplo Minimo, Completo y Verificable según lo indicado por el centro de ayuda propio y respuestas en meta. Propongo que esta parte enlace a una zona del centro de ayuda que se adentre a explicar que es un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable y, por supuesto, debemos hacer entender por que nos es tan importante ese detalle.

Si bien es cierto que esto se aclara más adelante, empezar con una afirmación así hace que el usuario crea que debe poner un fragmento de código. Y, por lo que he visto, incluso en comentarios y como persona que responde preguntas, un fragmento de código a veces no nos sirve.

###### Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

No veo muchos problemas aquí, pero vendría bien aclarar que, a pesar de la necesidad de que el ejemplo sea minimo, no implica que deba dejar de ser completo y verificable.

###### ¿Por qué algunas preguntas están marcadas "en espera"?

> Las preguntas que necesitan trabajo adicional o que no encajan en este
> sitio pueden ser puestas en espera por miembros experimentados de la
> comunidad.

No conozco esa funcionalidad en el sitio. Todas las preguntas que vi y vote por cerrar tienen un aviso de "cerrada". Pero si esta funcionalidad existe, vendría bien que se comunicara explicitamente para que sea mejor entendido lo que sucedió con la pregunta.

#### Normas no escritas

A continuación, mencionaré las normas no escritas que llegué a entender que se me ocurrieron que podrían estar en el centro de ayuda:

- **No editar una publicación en otro idioma para traducirla, ese es trabajo del OP. Si publicas en ingles, podrías recibir votos negativos y de cierre.** He visto muchas preguntas que han terminado así.
- **(esto es mencionado parcialmente por el centro de ayuda, pero no es tan claro) No respondas preguntas de baja calidad, esto no es bien recibido por la comunidad y podría traerte votos negativos.** He visto comentarios y votos negativos cuando este escenario ocurre.
- **La investigación incluye "buscar en internet", no solo dentro del sitio.** Analizado más arriba.
- Algunas preguntas no requieren investigación (esto no me queda claro por que ni que criterio se sigue, quien quiera aclararlo, bienvenido sea). Me ha parecido ver alguna que otra con este caso, pero no estoy seguro, si no es el caso, se puede descartar.
- **Cuando te piden "lo que intentaste" en realidad se está pidiendo un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable o una lista de algunos de los links visitados.** Esto si es una semi-suposición, pero estoy muy seguro por los puntos anteriores.

#### Razones para mejorar el centro de ayuda

- Podría haber más usuarios que podrán entender el funcionamiento del sitio, por lo que la calidad, y por lo tanto el recibimiento, de sus publicaciones mejoraría. Esto también ayudaría a que menos usuarios nuevos terminen con cuentas bloqueadas.
- Lo anterior haría que el trabajo de revisión sea menos costoso, pues no tendrían primeras publicaciones que se basaron en una ayuda con conceptos errados.

---

#### Sumado a esto

Estaría bueno ver una sección en el centro de ayuda donde estén publicaciones:

- que se centren en un tema especifico, pero que tengan variadas respuestas sobre distintos subtemas (del estilo [te he votado negativamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/158880))
- que sean votadas por la comunidad cada cierto tiempo (como las elecciones de moderador. Pero podemos saltar esta parte si da trabajo de más).

Comment: muchas gracias tomare en cuenta tu opinion para presentar una propuesta

Comment: Gracias! Pero esperemos la opinion de la comunidad primero. Además, se me ocurría que hagamos todos propuestas justo en esta publicación (me refiero a la pregunta)